# Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Qual é a diferença entre aspas simples e aspas duplas em PHP?

Ontem estava a trabalhar com uma string de um JSON do google calendar usei `explode('\n', ..` para separar uma string.

Quando usei o explode em `"Mon Jul 7, 2014 \n\u003cbr"`, com `"` deu-me:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "Mon Jul 7, 2014 \u003cbr" }
```

Quando usei o explode em `'Mon Jul 7, 2014 \n\u003cbr'`, com `'` deu-me:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "Mon Jul 7, 2014 " [1]=> string(8) "\u003cbr" }
```

O descrito em cima foi só um exemplo prático com que me deparei.
Seria interessante saber quais são as diferenças, em PHP, entre `'` e `"` ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### Aspas Simples

A documentação do PHP define que [**aspas simples**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) são literais simples, não processadas. As únicas exceções para escape são a as próprias aspas simples (`'\''`) e a barra (`'\\'`).

Exemplo:

```php
$teste = 1;
echo 'A caixa d\'água está vazia. \\ $teste';
```

A saída será:

> A caixa d'água está vazia. \ $teste

### Aspas Duplas

Já as [**aspas duplas**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) serão processadas, suportando mais caracteres de escape, tais como `\n`, `\r`, `\t` e outros. Além disso, variáveis serão expandidas (ou interpoladas), por exemplo: `"Meu nome é $nome!"`.

Exemplo:

```php
$teste = 1;
echo "A caixa d\'água está vazia. \\ $teste $teste2";
```

A saída será:

> A caixa d'água está vazia. \ 1 $teste2

Note que `$teste2` não está definida, então a String não será expandida.

## Heredoc e Nowdoc

Além dessas duas formas de representar Strings no código, existem ainda o [**heredoc**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) e o [**nowdoc**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), os quais permitem adicionar blocos de String mais facilmente. Note que o `heredoc` funciona como as aspas duplas, enquanto o `nowdoc` funciona como as aspas simples.

Exemplo de `heredoc`:

```php
$interpolacao = 'INTERPOLAÇÃO';

$str = <<<EOD
Exemplo de String
$interpolacao funciona aqui dentro
EOD;
```

Saída:

> Exemplo de String
>
> INTERPOLAÇÃO funciona aqui dentro

Exemplo de `nowdoc`:

```php
$interpolacao = 'INTERPOLAÇÃO';

$str = <<<'EOD'
Exemplo de String
$interpolacao não funciona aqui dentro
EOD;
```

Saída:

> Exemplo de String
>
> $interpolacao não funciona aqui dentro

Answer (score 17):

A diferença entre aspas simples e aspas duplas está na utilização.

**Aspas duplas permitem:**

**a)** que variáveis seja interpretadas dentro dela:

```
$nome = "bob";
echo "meu nome é $nome";
```

**b)** a utilização Utilização de escapes como : `\n ,\r, \t, \v, \e, \f, \\, \$, \"`;

**c)** a invocação de métodos/propriedades utilizando a *sintaxe completa*, ou seja, são necessários `{}`:

```
echo "{$pessoa->getNome()}";
```

**Aspas simples permitem:**

**a)** apenas os escapes `\'` e `\\`:

```
echo 'I\'m here'; //i'm here
echo 'I\'m \r\n here'//não vai gerar a quebra de linha.
```

Answer (score 13):

Como já dito nas outras respostas, aspas simples são literais e aspas duplas são interpretativas.

Por terem um consumo de memória diferente, um ponto importante na hora de escolher usar aspas simples ou duplas é o conteúdo que será adicionado a elas.

Se for usar texto puro, prefira usar as aspas simples que o consumo de memória será menor por não haver necessidade do PHP tentar interpretar o conteúdo.

```
$simples = 'Meu nome é Raul'; //consome menos memória
$duplas = "Meu nome é Raul"; //consome mais memória
```

Agora, se precisar concatenar este texto com variáveis é melhor usar as aspas duplas ao invés de usar ponto (.).

```
$simples = 'Meu nome é '.$nome; //consome mais memória
$duplas = "Meu nome é $nome"; //consome menos memória
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Aspas Simples

Reconhecem o conteúdo de forma literal, tudo será tratado como texto:

```
<?php
$valor = 10;
$variavel = 'meu número é $valor';
echo $variavel;
// Saida: meu número é $valor
```

#### Aspas Duplas

Reconhece caracteres de escape `\n` `\t` `\r` e `variáveis` no conteúdo:

```
<?php
$valor = 10;
$variavel = "meu número é $valor";
echo $variavel;
// Saida: meu número é 10
```

Answer (score 8):

No PHP, a aspas simples não é interpretativa, é uma string e apenas isso, já a dupla é processada, então pode conter variáveis que serão convertidas na hora de executar a string.

Por exemplo:

```
$foo = 'bar';

echo "Variavel $foo"; // Variavel bar
echo 'Variavel $foo'; // Variavel $foo
```

Answer (score 4):

Afim de reproduzir os comparativos de performance que muitos lugares apresentam colocando as *strings* com aspas simples como mais rápidas, utilizei a ferramenta de *profiling* Blackfire nas duas versões.

**Versão utilizando aspas simples**

```php
<?php // single.php

$string = 'Anderson Carlos Woss';
```

**Versão utilizando aspas duplas**

```php
<?php // double.php

$string = "Anderson Carlos Woss";
```

Perceba que diferente da maioria dos outros lugares eu não testarei dentro de um laço de repetição, pois isso tende a inserir muito ruído na amostra devido a várias considerações no gerenciamento de memória que o interpretador faz. Uma *string* fixa pode ser alocada em tempo de compilação e apenas reutilizada em tempo de execução, o que faria com que o resultado não reproduzisse fielmente o espaço amostral. Também não utilizei as funções de tempo da própria linguagem para aferir o tempo e não utilizei funções de entrada e saída para também não inserir ruído no resultado. O *script* tem como função apenas declarar a *string* das duas formas distintas.

Foi tomado um espaço de 1000 amostras e o resultado será baseado na média entre elas:

**Amostragem utilizando aspas simples**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Wall Time      87µs
I/O Wait        n/a
CPU Time        n/a
Memory       35.9KB
Network         n/a     n/a     n/a
SQL             n/a     n/a
```

**Amostragem utilizando aspas duplas**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Wall Time      86µs
I/O Wait        n/a
CPU Time        n/a
Memory       35.9KB
Network         n/a     n/a     n/a
SQL             n/a     n/a
```

Ou seja, em 1000 amostras, a média de diferença entre as duas versões foi de 1 μs (1 microssegundo, ou 0.000001 segundos), apontando inclusive as aspas duplas como menor tempo. A única conclusão que se tira disso é que não faz diferença entre utilizar aspas simples ou duplas em questão de performance para definir *strings* estáticas. Vale comentar que os tempos de I/O, CPU e rede foram nulos como era esperado e a memória utilizada foi a mesma, pois em ambas as soluções utilizou-se o mesmo conteúdo.

Comment: Se você for ver a nível individual, isso significa que usar aspas simples implicou 1 ns a mais para cada rodada. Esse tempo pode ser explicado facilmente pelo decaimento da função de onda do elétron