# Para que serve <<< EOH no PHP?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, heredoc

Vejo isso em várias classes de terceiros.

Lembrando que o fechamento geralmente é o `EOH`, mas sem `<<<`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Definição de strings em PHP

Como boa parte das linguagens, PHP permite definir *strings*, ou seja, sequências de caracteres literalmente, iniciando-as por aspas (`"`) , ou por ápice (`'`) - que alguns chamam de apóstrofo, plica ou aspas simples.

Além destas definições normais de string, o *PHP* também permite declarações multi-linha nos formatos *Heredoc*, e desde o *PHP 5.3* no formato *Nowdoc*, que é bem similar, como veremos.

> Os formatos *Heredoc* e *Newdoc* também são bons para se melhorar a legibilidade de strings que precisam ter tanto aspas simples quanto duplas. Adicionalmente, é bom lembrar que o *PHP* também permite strings multi-linha usando aspas, diferentemente de muitas linguagens.

### Sintaxe Heredoc:

A sintaxe do Heredoc é esta:

```
construct/variavel <<<IDENTIFICADOR
Aqui vão as linhas que
devem ser armazenadas na string.
Podemos incluir $variaveis, "aspas" e... \t caracteres especiais.
IDENTIFICADOR;
```

O *Heredoc* é indicado por `<<<` seguido de um identificador, à escolha do usuário. Porém, ao escolher este identificador, é adequado que seja uma string que não ocorra dentro do texto que vai ser delimitado, pois a próxima ocorrência da string no começo da linha pode confundir o parser.

De qualquer forma, o identificador final deve acontecer sozinho numa linha única, e conter apenas um `;` antes da quebra de linha.

Eis um trecho de código exemplificando o seu uso:

```
$nome = "Leandro";
$texto = <<<BATATINHAS
Olá, $nome. Este é um exemplo prático do Heredoc.
\nNeste caso, usamos o "Heredoc" com quebra de linha com
barra invertida, e troca da variável "nome".
BATATINHAS;
echo nl2br( htmlentities( $texto ) );
```

E sua saída, vista no browser, seria:

```
Olá, Leandro. Este é um exemplo prático do Heredoc.

Neste caso, usamos o "Heredoc" com quebra de linha com
barra invertida, e troca da variável "nome".
```

Notar que a variável $nome foi substituida por seu valor, e o \n na segunda linha convertido para uma quebra de linha (e em seguida por um `<br>` graças ao `nl2br`, mas isso ja é outro tópico). Seria comparável a uma string delimitada com `"`.

Nota: desde a introdução do *Nowdoc* no PHP 5.3, o *Heredoc* passou a aceitar aspas duplas no identificador. Leia mais a seguir.

### Sintaxe *Nowdoc*:

A sintaxe do *Nowdoc* é muito parecida com a do *Heredoc*, foi adicionada no PHP 5.3 como alternativa ao *Heredoc*:

```
construct/variavel <<<'IDENTIFICADOR'
Aqui vão as linhas que
devem ser armazenadas na string.
Aqui já não serao substituidos $variaveis e \t caracteres especiais.
IDENTIFICADOR;
```

O que muda é o identificador, que desta vez é colocado entre aspas simples. A diferença básica é que o *Nowdoc* interpreta o conteúdo literalmente, não fazendo a substituição dos caracteres especiais nem variáveis. É equivalente às strings delimitadas com o ápice (`'`).

Eis um trecho de código muito similar ao do *Heredoc*, exemplificando o seu uso:

```
$nome = "Leandro";
$texto = <<<'BATATINHAS'
Olá, $nome. Este é um exemplo prático do Nowdoc.
\nNeste caso, usamos o "Nowdoc" para mostrar que
não acontece substituição de caracteres.
BATATINHAS;
echo nl2br( htmlentities( $texto ) );
```

E sua saída, vista no browser, seria:

```
Olá, $nome. Este é um exemplo prático do Nowdoc.
\nNeste caso, usamos o "Nowdoc" para mostrar que
não acontece substituição de caracteres.
```

Notar que neste caso, o texto ficou idêntico ao da declaração inicial, preservando a string `$nome` e o `\n` originais.

> Veja mais sobre *strings*, *Heredoc* e *Nowdoc* no [manual do **PHP**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Pergunta relacionada:

> [Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/)

Demonstração no IDEONE, cortesia do [@GuilhermeNascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635):

> https://ideone.com/iXMesy

Comment: Perfeito! Ficou mais que claro.

Comment: Excelente! Rapaz você realmente me ajudou resolvi meu problema com o Newdoc, agora posso gerar arquivos com php dinamicamente. Muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: muito bom, acho que isso ajudará demais

Answer (score 11):

Isso é um método chamado **HEREDOC** é um alternativa pra não precisar usar aspas duplas para escrever em várias linhas. Veja mais [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) é equivalente ao `@"Texto"` do `C#`

Artigo do [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) sobre: *"is a file literal or input stream literal: it is a section of a source code file that is treated as if it were a separate file."*, traduzindo: É uma forma de tratar uma parte do código como se fosse outro arquivo, também conhecido como **literal**.

Comment: Bacana! Obrigado pela resposta.