# Função mail() do PHP

Tags: php, envio-de-email, email

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail via PHP com atributos HTML, um e-mail formatado com imagens e style="" ou classes. Já tentei utilizar o PHPMailer, porém sem sucesso, então recorri a função mail() do PHP que atende minhas necessidades e envia o e-mail sem muitos problemas, o único problema em si é que o e-mail não está autenticado e vive caindo na quarentena, posso fazer alguma ação para corrigir isto?
Outro problema, meu principal é que o e-mail não envia quando tento colocar tags como 
`<div style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;"></div>` e também quando tento acrescentar imagens com `<img src='http://meusite.com.br/templates-email/cabecalho.jpg' alt='img' />` (só um exemplo).

**A questão é:**

1. Como enviar e-mails com HTML utilizando a função mail() (incluindo imagens neste e-mail e divs). ?
2. Como solucionar o problema da autenticidade dos e-mails (vivem caindo em quarentena).

### TENTATIVA 1 (não envia).

```
//envia e-mail de confirmação
    $email_remetente = "nao-responda@bluecontract.com.br";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "From: $email_remetente\n"; // remetente
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $email_remetente\n"; // return-path
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_usuario\n"; // Endereço (devidamente validado) que o seu usuário informou no contato
    $texto_mensagem = "<html><head><title>Blue Contract - Ative sua conta</title></head><body>";
    $texto_mensagem .= "<div style=\'font: 14px Arial, Tahoma; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;\'>";
    $texto_mensagem .= "<img src='http://bluecontract.com.br/templates-email/cabecalho.jpg' alt='img' />";
    $texto_mensagem .= "<h1>Ativação de conta - Blue Contract</h1>";
    $texto_mensagem .= "<p>Através de nosso website, você efetuou um cadastro em ".$usuDataCadastro."</p>";
    $texto_mensagem .= "<p>Agora, para finalizar seu cadastro é necessário confirmar sua conta.</p>";
    $texto_mensagem .= "</div>";
    $texto_mensagem .= "</body></html>";

    $envio = mail(base64_decode($usuEmail), "Blue Contract - Ative sua conta", $texto_mensagem, $headers, "-f$email_remetente");

    // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
    if ($envio) { } else { header("Location: ".URL."criar-conta?tk=".$usuToken."&eee#ve"); exit(); }
```

### TENTATIVA 2

```
    //envia e-mail de confirmação
        $email_remetente = "nao-responda@bluecontract.com.br";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8\n";
        $headers .= "From: $email_remetente\n"; // remetente
        $headers .= "Return-Path: $email_remetente\n"; // return-path
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_usuario\n"; // Endereço (devidamente validado) que o seu usuário informou no contato

        $texto_mensagem = "<html>
                            <head>
                               <title>Blue Contract - Ative sua conta</title>
                            </head>

                            <body>
                            <div style=\'margin: 40px auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;\'>
                                <img src=\'http://bluecontract.com.br/templates-email/cabecalho.jpg\' width=\'100%\'/>
                            </div>
                            E-mail: <b>teste@gmail.com</b>
                            </body></html>";

         $envio = mail(base64_decode($usuEmail), "Blue Contract - Ative sua conta", $texto_mensagem, $headers, "-f$email_remetente");

         // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
         if ($envio) { } else { header("Location: ".URL."criar-conta?tk=".$usuToken."&eee#ve"); exit(); }
```

Tentei fazer dessas duas maneiras, ambas com o mesmo problema da imagem.

> Lembrando que **o envio de e-mail acontece**, então **meu problema não é que os e-mails não chegam ao destino**.

Comment: Eu gosto de usar o [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html). Acho ele mais simples.

Comment: Já ouvi falar do swiftmailer, porém nunca tive um contato com o código ou até mesmo cheguei a utilizá-lo, analisei o site agora e realmente parece ser muito simples. Ferramenta interessante também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema através do [**PHP Mailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Antes de tudo você deverá baixar o PHP Mailer e descompactar dentro da pasta de seu projeto, logo em seguida não se esqueça de incluir em seu arquivo .php

```
<?php
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"); // requer a class do PHPMAILER

//envia e-mail de confirmação
$usuEmail = "joaodasilva@email.com.br"; // email para onde será enviado (destinatário)
$usuNome = "João da Silva"; // nome para quem será enviado (destinatário)

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();  // send via SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.seusite.com.br'; //Endereço do seu Servidor de Email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // true se o email é autenticado
$mail->Port = '587'; // Porta para autenticação smtp geralmente é a 587;
$mail->Username = 'seuemail@seusite.com.br'; // Seu endereço de email que envia os email
$mail->Password = "SUA_SENHA"; // senha do usuário que envia o email

$mail->From = 'seuemail@seusite.com.br'; //a pessoa que ta enviando o email

$mail->FromName = 'NOME DO REMETENTE (ASSUNTO)'; //Nome de quem ta enviando...
$mail->AddAddress($usuEmail, $usuNome); //e-mail, nome
$mail->AddReplyTo("seuemail@seusite.com.br", "NOME DO MEU SITE/EMAIL"); //e-mail para respostas e nome do site ou email que receberá respostas

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // Quebra de linha
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Se for true é enviando email no formato HTML
$mail->Subject = "ASSUNTO DO EMAIL"; //Assunto do seu Email
$mail->Body = utf8_decode("
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<body>
<div style='min-height: 250px;'>
    <div style='font: 14px Arial, Tahoma; padding: 0 0 30px 0; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-radius: 5px;'>
        <img src='cid:cabecalho' width='100%'/>
        <h1>Ative sua conta</h1>
        <p>Através de nosso website, você efetuou um cadastro.</p>
        <p>Agora, para finalizar seu cadastro é necessário confirmar sua conta.</p>
        <br><a href='#' style='background: #006699; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; margin: 10px auto; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;'>Ative sua conta</a>
        <br>
        <p>Caso não esteja conseguindo utilizar este botão, copie e cole o link abaixo em seu navegador:</p><pre>meusite.com.br/ativar-conta </pre>

        <img src='cid:rodape' width='100%'/>

    </div>
</div>
</body>

"); //Conteudo HTML
$mail->AltBody = "Para mensagens somente texto"; //Somente Texto

//adiciona arquivos em anexo
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('pasta_da_imagem/cabecalho.jpg', 'cabecalho');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('pasta_da_imagem/rodape.jpg', 'rodape');

$envio = $mail->Send(); //envia o e-mail

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($envio) { echo "enviado"; } else { echo "O e-mail não pode ser enviado, ocorreu um erro"; }

//
?>
```

> O código funcional encontra-se acima, abaixo você encontrará apenas a explicação de como personalizá-lo e funcionamento.

### Como é feito o anexo dos arquivos no e-mail?

É uma solução bem simples, se analisar bem você verá que todo o anexo dos arquivos pode ser feito com apenas um linha de código:

```
//adiciona arquivos em anexo
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('pasta_da_imagem/cabecalho.jpg', 'cabecalho');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('pasta_da_imagem/rodape.jpg', 'rodape');
```

Caso queira adicionar mais anexos basta repetir a linha alterando o nome do arquivo e sua denominação. Ex.: `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('pasta_da_imagem/meuarquivo.jpg', 'nome_do_arquivo');`

### Como utilizar no HTML o anexo?

Para isto basta você utilizar `cid:nome_do_arquivo`, lembrando que após os dois pontos `:` você colocará o nome que você chamou seu arquivo ao anexá-lo no e-mail.

### Não quero deixar a senha exposta

Se você deseja evitar de deixar a senha exposta no arquivo, utilize algumas codificações que não são de mão única, mesmo que simples podem dificultar um pouco para leigos e a senha não fica facilmente à mostra. Um bom exemplo é [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php)
Você poderá utilizar algo como:

```
$mail->Password = base64_decode("SUA_SENHA_CRIPTOGRAFADA_COM_BASE64_ENCODE");
```

Comment: Tiago, e qual é a solução para o email não ir na pasta de spam ? Não está claro na sua resposta.

Comment: Neste caso os e-mails já estão autenticados, para não ir a pasta de SPAM como ocorre em alguns e-mails a solução em que encontrei foi não utilizar imagens em anexo, pois isto pode ser considerado SPAM. Outro caso é que se na variável `$mail->From` você colocar um endereço de e-mail diferente do que existe em seu site, ou até mesmo colocar um que não exista em sua hospedagem poderá fazer com que caia em SPAM.

Comment: Vale ressaltar também que na resposta do @Bacco logo aqui em cima http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36912/6392 ele citou algo como `registros SPF no servidor de DNS do domínio`, não entendi muito bem sobre como funciona, dei uma pesquisada mas vale a pena tentar se informar mais, talvez solucione os problemas.

Answer (score 6):

Creio que a pergunta tenha mero erro de sintaxe, pois o seu HTML deve estar sendo enviado um monte de barras invertidas indevidamente. Provavelmente isto resolva:

```
$texto_mensagem = '
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Blue Contract - Ative sua conta</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div style="margin: 40px auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://bluecontract.com.br/templates-email/cabecalho.jpg" width="100%" />
      </div>
      E-mail: <b>teste@gmail.com</b>
      </body>';
```

Ou melhor ainda, usando **[HEREDOC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14241/70)**:

```
$texto_mensagem = <<<FINAL
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Blue Contract - Ative sua conta</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div style="margin: 40px auto; margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://bluecontract.com.br/templates-email/cabecalho.jpg" width="100%" />
      </div>
      E-mail: <b>teste@gmail.com</b>
      </body>
 FINAL;
```

Adicionalmente, seus headers devem ser separados por CR LF, ( \r\n ), ou seja `chr( 13 ) . chr( 10 )`:

```
$crlf = chr(13).chr(10) //coloquei em variável apenas para facilitar testes
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$crlf;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8".$crlf;
$headers .= "From: $email_remetente".$crlf; // remetente
$headers .= "Return-Path: $email_remetente".$crlf; // return-path
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_usuario".$crlf; //
```

E para ajudar o *debug*, convém substituir o `base64_decode` por um endereço literal para testes.

### Quanto à autenticidade dos emails

Uma das coisas que pode ajudar, é examinar os cabeçalhos do original recebido pela parte, para analisar os motivos do bloqueio. Uma provável melhoria seria adicionar registros SPF no servidor de DNS do domínio, autorizando a máquina que envia os emails como confiável.

Exemplo: permitindo envio de qualquer IP entre 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.255.255:

```
"v=spf1 ip4:192.168.0.1/16 -all"
```

Basta adicionar uma entrada TXT com os dados acima, por exemplo. Não se esqueça de incluir todas as possíveis fontes de email válido no domínio nas regras. O assunto merece um estudo mais aprofundado.

Veja mais sobre SPF no **[Antispam Br](http://www.antispam.br/admin/spf/)**.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, as barras invertidas neste caso utilizei na tentativa de escapar as aspas simples/duplas, já tentei também sem barras invertidas, na real foram as primeiras tentativas e não obtive sucesso. Tentei com o código que você passou e também não tive sucesso.