# Form em JS com mensagem de Success e Fail

Tags: php, javascript, formulário

há dias venho procurando um bom tutorial, explicando do começo, meio e fim para a criação de um form com envio (PHP e JS), porém sem dar reload na página e também onde apresente uma msg (div), em verde se o e-mail foi enviado corretamente e em vermelho, caso não tenha ido ou faltado alguma informação obrigatória no form.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Ponhamos o seguinte form, simples, que envia um email ao email introduzido e dá um retorno simples no form dizendo "Obrigado".

### HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <label for="email">Escreva por favor o seu email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    <div id="avisos"></div>
</form>
```

Aqui tens um form, um input e um botão com o tipo `submit` que quando pressionado dispara o evento `submit` da form que o JavaScript vai usar/interceptar.

### JavaScript:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');

function validar(email) {
    email = email.split(' ').join(''); // retirar espaços vazios
    if (!email) return false;          // caso email esteja vazio
    if (!email.match(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/)) return false; // verificação generalista
    return true;
}

function enviar(email, info) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            info.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.open('POST', 'http://seusite.com/enviar.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.send('email=' + email);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var avisos = document.getElementById('avisos');
    var email = this.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
    var ok = validar(email.value);
    if (ok) return enviar(email.value, avisos);
    else return avisos.innerHTML = 'O email não está bem preenchido';
});
```

Aqui tens 3 partes diferentes. O `form.addEventListener` intercepta o evento `submit` e pára-o com `e.preventDefault();` para a página não ter um refresh.

Depois envia o email para uma função `validar` que retorna um *Booleano* para sabermos se o email estava ok ou se tinha problemas. Se tido estiver OK manda para a função que faz o pedido ajax. Caso contrário dá erro ao utilizador.

Por final é enviado o email para o servidor. Se quiseres usar este script tens de usar o teu dominio/url aqui. Eu testei agora este código no meu servidor e tudo funcionou bem.

### PHP:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
// fazer mais verificações e adicionar à base de dados aqui...

$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Newsletter';
$message = 'Obrigado!';
$headers = 'From: voce@seusite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: oce@seusite.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($ok) echo $message;
else echo 'Houver um problema com o envio de email...';
?>
```

Por fim no PHP, bem simples o exemplo, envia um email para o email que foi recebido e retorna para o JavaScript `Obrigado!` que vai ser colocado na página para o utilizador saber que está tudo bem.

#### Conclusão:

A tua pergunta é bam ampla e eu deixo uma resposta que funciona mas que toca somente ao de leve nos passos que tens de dar. Podes ainda ler mais aqui no SOpt sobre [como verificar emails em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8134/129), [a função mail do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36912/129), [login e senhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3571/129), [como evitar refresh da página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129), etc etc...  Dá uma olhada ao código e se tiveres problemas sugiro que faças uma pergunta à parte, sobre o problema específivo. Aí será possível responder com mais detalhe.