# Remover Registro em jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Gostaria de ao efetuar um clique em Apagar, apague o registro do banco de dados mySQL.. Sem dar reload na pagina... usando jquery.. Alguém sabe informar? Grato

Comment: Você vai precisar fazer uma requisição Ajax a um PHP que apaga o registro do banco. Em que parte exatamente está tendo dificuldade?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70385/129 acho que tem a maior parte do que precisas. Explica depois o que te falta e não consegues fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo deletando um registro:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){

        // Pega o id
        var product_id = $(this).closest('td').find('.product-id').text();

        // Gatilho para deletar o registro
        $.post("delete.php", { id: product_id })
            .done(function(data){
                console.log(data);

                // Mostra uma imagem de carregando
                $('#loader-image').show();

                // Re-carrega a lista de produtos
                showProducts();

            });
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Incluido para pegar a conexão com a base
include_once 'config/database.php';

try {

    $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['id']);

    // Executa o SQL
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Product was deleted.";
    }else{
        echo "Unable to delete product.";
    }
}

// Ao ocorrer erro
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
?>
```