# Posso escrever em JavaScript dentro de PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, interoperabilidade

Posso escrever em [php](/questions/tagged/php) a tag [html](/questions/tagged/html)`<script>` e aqui dentro escrever o script JavaScript `</script>` usando `echo`?

Se eu fizer por exemplo `echo("<script> var a = 'texto';</script>");`

Este é o meu código mas o JS não funciona:

```
$color = "red";
echo("
 <script>
  function change_background(var cor)
  {
     if(cor == 'red')
     {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = red;
     }
  }
 </script>
 <button onclick='change_background('".$color."')'>$color</button>

");
```

Por bem decidi postar as minhas perguntas semelhantes

[Posso fazer o JavaScript escrever PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90095/posso-fazer-o-javascript-escrever-php)

[Posso escrever o ajax e javascript juntos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90102/posso-escrever-o-ajax-e-javascript-juntos)

Comment: Pode sim, estás tendo algum erro com isso?

Comment: O javascript não funciona eu devo ter algo errado então

Comment: Eu não acho isso uma boa idéia. Mas dá pra fazer uma coisinha legal usando ob_start

Comment: Peço que você considere a minha resposta como um exemplo para melhorar essas práticas. Creio que a resposta do @bigown já foi esclarecedora pra você.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## JavaScript como texto

Se a sua dúvida é saber se pode criar um texto que contém um código JS que será inserido junto com o texto HTML que está gerando com o PHP. Sim, pode.

O que o PHP faz é apenas isto, gerar um texto "linguição" que será enviado para o servidor HTTP que enviará para o navegador ou quem tenha pedido. Pode ser até que não seja uma página HTML que esteja fazendo. Entenda o código PHP como um grande processador de texto.

Claro que ele pode fazer muito mais que isto, mas na forma como ele costuma ser usado o resultado final sempre será o texto que pode conter qualquer coisa que você quiser, pode ter HTML, JS, CSS, JSON, texto comum sem formatação, ou outro formato qualquer. Na verdade nem precisa ser texto, este é o tipo de dado gerado para saída mais comum. Se o texto tem algo errado dentro dele, não é problema do PHP.

Pode parecer confuso porque é o código de uma linguagem dentro do código de outra linguagem. Estes códigos não tem relação entre si. Eles não "conversam", até porque o código do JS não é executado pelo PHP, pra ele isto é apenas um texto qualquer, só você sabe que aquilo é JS. Quando está programado pense no código PHP de forma independente do JS. O problema de um não é problema do outro.

O `echo` é justamente para isto, tudo o que você "imprime" no PHP será enviado para o servidor HTTP. Pelo menos esta é a forma mais comum de usar o PHP (é possível usar de outras formas, mas a maioria dos programadores não sabem fazer isto e nem sabem que é possível). Obviamente que onde colocar este `echo` no código é importante para atingir o resultado esperado.

Já tentou ver no navegador o resultado de um página gerada com PHP? Faça experimentos tentando enviar de formas diferentes e sempre que tiver dúvidas específicas, poste aqui dando o máximo de detalhes possível do que está fazendo e qual o problema.

## JavaScript executando

Se quer saber se pode inserir este código JS dentro do próprio código PHP e executar nele mesmo, aí a resposta é não, não pode fazer isto, são linguagens distintas. Até pode existir alguma forma de chamar um mecanismo que execute o JS externamente, mas é algo que ninguém faz e é algo esquisito mesmo. Não vejo motivos para fazer isto.

## Problema específico

Note que o ideal é que você não tenha código JS inserido dentro de uma página HTML. Seria melhor ter todo código JS em um arquivo separado, e de preferência que este arquivo fosse estático, ou seja, que fosse fixo e não gerado na hora.

Gerar código JS dinamicamente via PHP geralmente faz pouco sentido na maioria das vezes. Inserir ele dentro do JS também não costuma ser necessário, embora possa ser usado sem problemas.

Após a edição da pergunta vejo que o código está fazendo o que deseja, ou não? Colocou ele para executar? Ele apareceu no navegador? É isto. Claro que este código pressupõe que exitam outras partes HTML ou mesmo JS na mesma página ou arquivo adicional.

Mas eu tenho minhas dúvidas se precisa gerar todo este código JS em PHP. Eu acho que dá para deixar o JS separado e configurar para ele manipular a cor por parâmetro e só a cor ser inserida na chamada deste código. Precisa ver um contexto maior. Mas reforço o que disse antes, em geral não tem porque gerar códigos JS pelo PHP.

Se o JS não está gerado ok e não funciona, o problema é outro do descrito na pergunta, então deve abrir outra pergunta com o problema específico dele. Poste o resto do código da página nesta nova pergunta. Acredito não ser necessário nada do PHP, até porque nem nesta foi colocado efetivamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado esclareceu minha duvida eu sabia que html conseguia colocar dentro do php mas não sabia que ainda conseguiria coloca javascript dentro.

Comment: Note que no fundo você está colocando HTML que por acaso dentro dele tem JS. Mas poderia por JS puro também.

Comment: estou ainda aprender então estou experimentar é o melhor caminho

Comment: Muito bem esclarecido, gostaria de adicionar a informação que  muitas vezes o arquivo JS fica como cache, ou seja, mesmo que sofra uma atualização dinâmica pelo Php, quem acessa o site continua tendo acesso ao arquivo antigo por causa do cache.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode sim.

O problema é que isso dificulta um pouco a leitura do seu código (em javascript), já que ele é uma string PHP, e dificilmente o seu editor de texto vai sinalizar que a sintaxe está correta ou não.

Eu não sei qual é a finalidade disso, mas existem outras coisas que o PHP pode fazer que você pode levar em conta na hora de utilizar um javascript em conjunto.

## função ob_start

A função `ob_start` permite capturar o buffer de saída que o PHP gera para a memória. Sendo assim, é possível capturar essa saída (antes de ir para o navegador, a grosso modo) e salvá-la numa string.

Exemplo

```
<?php if ($alguma_coisa): ?>
<?php ob_start() ?>
<script>
alert('vou parar dentro do php');
</script>
<?php 
   $buffer_js = ob_get_clean();
    var_dump($buffer_js);
?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Isso pode ser útil se você quiser escrever o seu código javascript normalmente (como o conteúdo de um HTML, ao invés de uma string PHP) e guardá-lo na memória. Quando chamamos a função `ob_get_clean()` estamos capturando o que foi guardado no buffer e encerrando a captura do mesmo - ou seja, só o trecho javascript será pego.

## função file_get_contents

Se realmente é necessário, já pensou na possibilidade de abrir um arquivo javascript pelo PHP e imprimi-lo como string?

```
<script>
<?php echo file_get_contents('meu_arquivo.js') ?>
</script>
```

## HEREDOC

Uma outra boa ideia é utilizar a [Sintaxe Heredoc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14241/para-que-serve-eoh-no-php/14258#14258). Mas ao utilizar ela você não vai ficar preocupado se tem que usar `'` aspas simples ou `"` aspas duplas.

```
$script = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('teste'); alert("teste");
</script>
EOT;
```

## Conclusão

Eu particurlamente já escrevi um código para poder debugar valores do PHP através do console do navegador. Para isso escrevi um pequeno código dessa forma:

```
function js_console_log($mixed) {
  printf('<script>console.log(%s);</script>', json_encode($mixed));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tira a palavra var do argumento da função, e vê se funciona, conforme abaixo:

```
$color = "red";
echo("
 <script>
  function change_background(cor)
  {
     if(cor == 'red')
     {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = red;
     }
  }
 </script>
 <button onclick='change_background('".$color."')'>$color</button>

");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = red;
```

troque o `red` por `cor`. Não existe a variavel `red`.