# Posso fazer o JavaScript escrever PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Posso fazer o [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) escrever [php](/questions/tagged/php)?

Relacionado:

[Posso escrever em JavaScript dentro de PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89802/posso-escrever-em-javascript-dentro-de-php)

[Posso escrever o ajax e javascript juntos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90102/posso-escrever-o-ajax-e-javascript-juntos)

Comment: Pra qual finalidade? A pergunta está muito ampla.

Comment: Preciso fazer o javascript escrever uma variavel php

Comment: `print('php')` :P

Comment: PHP é processado do lado do servidor, não sei se essa finalidade é possivel(ou até mesmo util), sendo que é possivel fazer ambas "conversarem" atraves do ajax. Dê uma pesquisada a respeito de ajax.

Comment: @renan posso fazer então print('<?php $variavel=' . valor . '?>'); ?

Comment: Veja a resposta do @bigown.

Comment: ******Não******

Comment: Pode criar um arquivo com doctype do tipo PHP em javascript e depois executá-lo via javascript. Mas isso é uma tremenda babaquisse.
https://robsonmagno.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/ler-gravar-e-criar-txt-com-javascript/

Comment: até porque só funciona no IE lixo.

Comment: Você pode escrever arquivos em javascript:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Essencialmente não.

E muitos programadores não entendem isto. Eles não entendem o que falei [naquela pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89802/posso-escrever-em-javascript-dentro-de-php). O PHP apenas gera um texto que por coincidência pode ser um código JS, o PHP nem sabe o que é aquilo.

Um JS dentro de um código PHP não executará no servidor, ele é apenas um texto, para o PHP aquilo não é um código.

O JS vai rodar no cliente, provavelmente um navegador e não tem contato direto com o PHP. O contato entre o código JS no cliente e o código PHP no servidor se dará por comunicação através do protocolo HTTP. Ou seja, o JS pode enviar dados para o servidor que passará para o código PHP decidir o que fazer com ele. Só isto.

Exemplo simplificado:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
       // faz alguma coisa - por ex. usando req.responseText
    }
    req.open("GET", "pagina.php", true);
    req.send();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/AJAX/Example.js).

Claro que pode usar o [JS no servidor](https://nodejs.org/en/) para auxiliar o PHP em alguma tarefa e até gerar um código PHP para o servidor executar, mas é algo separado e não é o que as pessoas costumam fazer, provavelmente porque é complexidade demais e ganho de menos.

Dentro do uso "normal" do PHP, não pode.

Comment: sendo assim não posso fazer isto 'print('<?php $variavel=' . valor . '?>'); ' ?

Comment: Poder, pode, mas não fará o que você está pensando.

Comment: então posso criar um cookie com javascript e fazer o php ler esse cookie ?

Comment: Você pretende trocar informações entre JS e PHP usando cookies? Creio que seja melhor via ajax.

Comment: Pode comunicar ele através do protocolo HTTP. O *cookie* só existe no cliente, e este tem que informar o servidor da existência dele. O navegador faz isto pelo protocolo. Também é possível enviar via JS.

Comment: O perfeito vou experimentar usar ajax

Answer (score 14):

Não pode pois o javascript trabalha no lado cliente do ciclo do http e o php trabalha no lado servidor, logo o código gerado pelo javascript nunca será executado no servidor, será apenas uma string/texto comum contendo instruções php.

Se você precisa fazer o javascript trabalhar com algum recurso do php utilize ajax.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é **sim**, mas não para o propósito que você quer. 
Utilizando o *Node.js* é possível escrever arquivos:

**Obs:** todas as linguagens escrevem arquivos. Mas nem todas trabalham em conjunto.

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Olá Mundo!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Nada foi salvo!');
});
```

No .htaccess, basta colocar isso e o seus arquivos txt passam a serem php:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .txt
```

Aqui tem mais informações a respeito:
**https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html**

Aqui tem um outro exemplo prático de que é possível gravar arquivos e se salvar um txt com a extensão ".php", vira um arquivo PHP:

[**Demo de exemplo**](https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/)

[**Github FileSaver**](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)