# Como fazer disso uma função a aplicá-la a uma variável PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#timer').countdown({
            until: new Date("2015-11-04 12:00:00"),
            compact: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Eu preciso transformar o ***código acima numa função*** e posteriormente aplicar esta função a uma variável PHP que está dentro de um loop. Como fazer isso?

```
while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {

     echo $datafinal;           // Y-m-d h:i:s

}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90095/posso-fazer-o-javascript-escrever-php você não pode enviar variaveis do js para php

Comment: E tem outra solução @AmadeuAntunes?

Comment: você pode enviar a data a partir do php para o js assim a data seria uma variavel php e poderia usar ela abaixo, pode usar AJAX mas acho que não seria necessario

Comment: Será que é isso que você está querendo? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58958/passar-vari%C3%A1vel-php-para-javascript

Comment: Eu preciso dentro de um loop de data recuperada no banco de dados implementar um countdown. Como poderia fazer isso pessoal? http://axitech.com.br/ccl/

Comment: Você pode enviar para o PHP a saída da sua função.

Comment: Achei interessante mas não entendi muito bem. Pode me explicar isso @IvanFerrer? Acho que isso pode resolver.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, coloquei a solução como resposta.

Comment: E qual é sua dúvida em relação a resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é utilizando AngularJS:

Modelo com contador: **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/b60djmho/**

Modelo onde você seta o intervalo inicial e final do contador: **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1cyxoytv/**

Modelo com jquery:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/wvfkbmf5/**

Não creio que precise usar PHP para criar um countdown.
Você passa a data inicial e a data final, e tem um atributo de formatação para a saída na view.