# variavel php dentro de linha javascript (Sweet Alert) PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, sweetalert

Estou criando uma mensagem utilizando o recurso *Sweet Alert*, e onde preciso apresentar o nome da pessoa dentro de um *Alert* vindo de uma variável *PHP*.Assim, Gostaria de saber como posso fazer corretamente.

Obs:. A conexão com o banco de dados está funcionando perfeitamente.

```
            echo "<script>    
                    swal({   
        title: 'Usuário Cadastrado.',   
        text: 'Gostaria de cadastrar os documentos do usuário **<?php echo $usuario ['nome']?>**?',   
        type: 'success',   
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                    showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: '#00c292',   
        confirmButtonText: 'Sim, Cadastrar',   
        closeOnConfirm: true 
    }, function(){   
        window.location.href = 'novo_usuario'; 
    });

                </script>";
  }
      ?>
```

Repare que na linha eu informei o código PHP

```html
text: 'Gostaria de cadastrar os documentos do usuário **<?php echo $usuario ['nome']?>**?',
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Posso fazer o JavaScript escrever PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90095/posso-fazer-o-javascript-escrever-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já "abriu" com o `<?php` no começo, não precisa abrir de novo basta concatenar com a variavel

```
echo "<script>
      swal({   
        title: 'Usuário Cadastrado.',   
        text: 'Gostaria de cadastrar os documentos do usuário ** {$usuario ['nome']}**?',   
        type: 'success',   
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                    showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: '#00c292',   
        confirmButtonText: 'Sim, Cadastrar',   
        closeOnConfirm: true 
    }, function(){   
        window.location.href = 'novo_usuario'; 
    });

                </script>";
```

Ou

```
echo "<script>
          swal({   
            title: 'Usuário Cadastrado.',   
            text: 'Gostaria de cadastrar os documentos do usuário ** " .$usuario ['nome'] ."**?',   
            type: 'success',   
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                        showCancelButton: true,   
            confirmButtonColor: '#00c292',   
            confirmButtonText: 'Sim, Cadastrar',   
            closeOnConfirm: true 
        }, function(){   
            window.location.href = 'novo_usuario'; 
        });

                    </script>";
```

Comment: Utilizei o seu exemplo 2 concatenando e funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço a sua grande ajuda Taynan