# Posso escrever o ajax e javascript juntos?

Tags: javascript, ajax

algum problema de escrever javascript e ajax juntos pois ambos são escritos dentro das tags `<script></script>` ?

Está ligado com esta questão

Posso por exemplo dentro das tags escrever uma função em javascript e depois uma funçao em [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)?

vem na continuidade desta questão [Posso escrever em JavaScript dentro de PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89802/posso-escrever-em-javascript-dentro-de-php)

Por bem achei util listar as minhas perguntas semelhantes

[Posso escrever em JavaScript dentro de PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89802/posso-escrever-em-javascript-dentro-de-php)

[Posso fazer o JavaScript escrever PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90095/posso-fazer-o-javascript-escrever-php)

Comment: Como assim "escrever javascript e ajax juntos"? Ajax é JavaScript...

Comment: AJAX é uma tecnologia que se utiliza do JS, ela não é outra linguagem: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) Então a pergunta não faz sentido.

Comment: Amigo, a definição de AJAX é Asynchronous Javascript and XML, ou seja, Ajax é Javascript, reformule sua pergunta para que fique mais fácil entender o que deseja fazer.

Comment: Respondeu à minha pergunta então javascript = ajax com outras funçoes

Comment: **Atenção** javascript não é = ajax, `XMLHttpRequest` (o ajax) é uma *API* do javascript, então ao "escrever ajax", você já está fazendo javascript, assim como o `FileReader` é outra *API* do javascript.

Comment: Um pouco de conteúdo sobre ... http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3585/ajax-basico-introducao.aspx

Comment: E caso ainda não esteja claro, você nunca "escreve ajax", escreve sempre javascript. O javascript pode envolver ajax (pense em ajax como uma operação), ou não.

Comment: Bastava teres pesquisado _"Ajax ou Javascript"_ no google, e terias a resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AJAX é JavaScript, é uma sigla que quer dizer *Asynchronous JavaScript and XML*, JavaScript e XML assincrono.

Quer seja AJAX nativo (com as ferramentas nativas do JavaScript) ou com a camada abstrata de uma biblioteca como o [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Request/Request), [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) ou outra, é JavaScript na mesma. Uma biblioteca pode dar mais métodos e ferramentas mas é tudo escrito em JavaScript.

Assim escrever JavaScript dentro de tags `<script></script>` é correto e consequentemente AJAX também.