# Existe a possibilidade de codigo javascript interagir com codigo php?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu sei que **javascript** e uma linguagem clinte side que e interpretada pelo browser do cliente e que **PHP** e uma linguagem server side interpretada pelo servidor mas sera que e possivel um codigo **javascript** ser usado dentro de um codigo **PHP** vou deixar uma page como exemplo.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Javascript & PHP</h1>
<script>
x = 1;
</script>
<?php
echo($x)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Veja também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89802/101

Comment: interessante sera que com a funcao print() do python tambem e possivel gerar codigo javascript?

Comment: Dessa forma que você exemplificou não é possível... você pode utilizar o php para gerar código javascript como o @bigown comentou ou pode utilizar XMLHttpRequest para buscar informações de um código php. segue documentação sobre o XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest