# Existe diferença de performance entre "echo" de um conteúdo e o conteúdo no HTML?

Tags: php, html, desempenho

O uso do `echo` do PHP para exibir na tela um conteúdo qualquer difere em **performance** de usar esse mesmo conteúdo direto no HTML?

Por exemplo, se eu usar num arquivo PHP:

```
<?php echo "<p>Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow!</p>";
```

Seria diferente em performance de usar nesse mesmo arquivo PHP?

```
<p>Seja Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow!</p>
```

Eu poderia usar tanto um como outro, como o conteúdo era estático, não me importei muito em usar o HTML direto.

É óbvio que se trata de um exemplo simples, na aplicação a situação é outra. Estou perguntando principalmente devido ao tempo de carregamento da página.

Se existirem outras diferenças que achem relevantes complementar na resposta, coloquem as mesmas.

Comment: O segundo é muito mais rápido por não usar o php :P, se o arquivo for .html.

Comment: rray até imaginei isso? mas porque? o php chega a ser pesado, consome muito ou algo do tipo?

Comment: DiegodeSouzaSilva o que o @rray falou é se não passar pelo php :) E tem ainda a questão das aspas duplas serem mais lentas (edit, isso deveria ser verdade, mas o PHP faz umas barbeiragens com escape em aspa simples, que fica lento tb).

Comment: Tem isso ainda? Dessa eu não sabia...

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva aspas duplas o PHP busca por variáveis pra substituir. Use sempre as simples, se for texto puro, aí o PHP nao tem que fazer parse do conteúdo (edit: num mundo ideal. a implementação atual tb enrosca em aspa simplespor causa do escape). Mesma coisa em [HEREDOC e NOWDOC](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14241/14258).

Comment: @rray acho que as vezes se preocupar com esse "mais rápido" é besteira. Se estiver usando um framework (ou mesmo não tiver configurado seu php.ini), o output buffer vai guardar tudo na memória para, somente no final, enviar ao navegador.

Comment: Se o texto é fixo em um arquivo `html` o php nem é processado, é só tempo do servidor achar o arquivo solicitado e devolver ao cliente. Acho que pessoal gostou da primeira parte da frase pelo php ser uma linguagem interpretada logo não tem uma boa performace se comparada as linguagens compiladas.

Comment: Bom deixa eu ver se eu entendi, então se eu usar dois arquivos php, um somente usando echo para imprimir x quantidade de conteúdo e outro arquivo php usando o html para exibir essa mesma quantidade de conteúdo, o arquivo html vai carregar mais rápido sempre (mesmo que por milésimos, centésimos, etc) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## HTML puro

HTML puro é absurdamente mais rápido. É um arquivo estático que não precisa de nenhum processamento, carregar o PHP para processá-lo, nada. Pá, pum, pediu, enviou.

## Usando PHP

Se o PHP for usado para processar o arquivo, aí depende da quantidade de texto HTML que ele terá que analisar, mas o fato de ter um mínimo já é absurdamente mais lento.

A [documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) diz que usar o HTML é mais eficiente.

> For outputting large blocks of text, dropping out of PHP parsing mode is generally more efficient than sending all of the text through echo or print
>
> Para escrever grandes blocos de texto, sair do modo de *parse* do PHP geralmente é mais eficiente que enviar todo texto através de um `echo` ou `print`

Isso ocorre porque o *parser* passa trabalhar em regime simplificado entendendo que aquilo é só um texto que ele não precisa entender o significado. Quando ele está em uma parte do texto que ele entende que é PHP (por *tag* específica), ele está interpretando o código, e isto é extremamente mais complicado de fazer e portanto mais lento.

Não vi testes e informações adicionais, mas o texto dá a entender que se os blocos de código forem pequenos, a troca de contexto do *parser* pode tornar mais lento fazer dessa forma e o `print` seria mais rápido. Embora eu duvide que dê muita diferença.

Quer ter certeza? Teste no seu ambiente. E lembre-se que o que vale hoje, pode não valer amanhã. E não confie muito nos resultados :P

[Achei um teste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2715153/221800) se quiser ter uma base, mas não tome ele como verdade absoluta.

## Otimização prematura

Como eu sempre digo, se a performance afetar então trocar de linguagem é que deveria ser a solução. PHP dá conta do recado em quase tudo, mesmo tendo essas diferenças. Não é importante analisar estes pequenos detalhes para obter performance, o ganho será muito pequeno.

[Otimização prematura é um mal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29507/101). Não de todo, mas tem que saber onde otimizar. Ficar procurando otimizar tudo o que faz é uma das piores coisas que um desenvolvedor pode fazer. Se toda esta otimização é necessária, PHP não é a linguagem adequada. E quando a pessoa corre atrás disto tem que reconhecer que está usando o [martelo dourado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

## Otimização ideal

Claro que o "ideal" seria uma separação completa do que é PHP e o que é HTML. Não sendo possível, seria bom minimizar o uso de PHP em um arquivo que seja para montar o *layout* da página e evitar o uso de HTML no código PHP.

Eu não usaria o PHP onde não precisa, então nesse exemplo simples eu não daria `echo`.

## Conclusão

Então prefira usar HTML sem passar pelo PHP. Se não der, tente usar o mínimo de PHP possível. Se precisar muito PHP e pouco HTML, então o `echo`/`print` pode ser melhor, especialmente com aspas simples.

Tem que pensar na legibilidade também, misturar muito fica estranho de ler, mesmo que tenha ganho de performance não vale a perda.

[Interessante leitura](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180504/389).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Todo conteúdo que for estático, e não precisar parsear numa outra linguagem independente de ser PHP, ASP, JSP, CGI, Ruby, despache como conteúdo estático.

No exemplo da pergunta, o primeiro código precisa ser interpretado pelo compilador do PHP, por isso, obviamente há um custo maior de tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo que uma otimização seja "imperceptível", é recomendável construir o scripts da forma mais otimizada possível. Mas nesse ponto vamos entrar numa discussão sobre performance, otimizações, boas práticas e todo aquele mimimi que tornaria a resposta fora de foco e complexa ou algo confuso e generalizado demais. Por isso me abstenho em estender para esse lado.

Comment: Sua ilustração está muito boa e explicação também!

Answer (score 2):

Sobre o carregamento da página: não muda, o que muda é no servidor. O echo **pode** impactar levemente a renderização, pois vai executar uma instrução que não precisaria (não sei como o php trata isso). mas o usuário vai receber o mesmo conteúdo, com ou sem a utilização do echo.