# Lidando com várias linhas de códigos dentro de uma váriavel

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório dinamico com mPDF, porém não estou conseguindo colocar meus dados dentro de uma váriavel para poder dar output nela.

A minha pagina está arquitetada assim:

```
$html = '<div class="box-content no-padding table-responsive relMembros">'
.'<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-heading table-datatable" id="tabMembros">'
.'    <thead>'
.'        <tr>'
.'            <th>Nome</th>'
.'            <th>Telefone</th>'
.'            <th>Aniversario</th>'
.'            <th>Email</th>'
.'            <th>Úsuario mobile</th>'
.'            <th>Status</th>'
.'        </tr>'
.'    </thead>'
.'    <tbody>';
        $conexao = new ConexaoDatabase();

        $sql = "MINHA QUERY";

        $sqlVars = array();
        $sqlVars[':igj'] = $suc->getCOD_IDENT_IGREJ();

        $registros = $conexao->fetchAll($sql, $sqlVars);

        if ($registros) {

            foreach ($registros as $registro) {

                echo '<tr>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_NOMEX_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_FONEX_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->DAT_NASCI_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_EMAIL_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->FLG_USUAR_MOBIL . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->FLG_STATU_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '</tr>';
            }
        } else {
            //echo 'Não existe vinculo para está pessoa.';
        }                     
    $html = $html . '</tbody>'
.'</table>'
.'</div>';

include("../pdf/mpdf60/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->list_number_suffix = ')';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Para abrir esta página estou utilizando AJAX para carregar o miolo do meu index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, você está misturando variável com jogar dados na tela, veja a diferença:

```
if ($registros) {

            foreach ($registros as $registro) {

                $html = $html . '<tr>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_NOMEX_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_FONEX_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->DAT_NASCI_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_EMAIL_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->FLG_USUAR_MOBIL . '</td>'
                . '<td>' . $registro->FLG_STATU_PESSO . '</td>'
                . '</tr>';
            }
        } else {
            //echo 'Não existe vinculo para está pessoa.';
        }
```

Além disso, isto aqui pode ser simplificado:

```
$html = $html . '<tr>'
```

é o mesmo que

```
$html .= '<tr>'
```

O que permite isso:

```
$html .= '<tr>'
  . '<tr>'
  . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_NOMEX_PESSO . '</td>'
  . '<td>' . $registro->DAT_NASCI_PESSO . '</td>'
  ...
```

### Usando o HEREDOC:

O PHP já tem um método adequado para grandes blocos de texto, veja ele aplicado ao seu código:

```
$html = <<<CODIGO
<div class="box-content no-padding table-responsive relMembros">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-heading table-datatable" id="tabMembros">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th>Aniversario</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Úsuario mobile</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
CODIGO;

    $conexao = new ConexaoDatabase();

    $sql = "MINHA QUERY";
    $sqlVars = array();
    $sqlVars[':igj'] = $suc->getCOD_IDENT_IGREJ();

    $registros = $conexao->fetchAll($sql, $sqlVars);

    if ($registros) {
        foreach ($registros as $registro) {
            $html .= <<<CODIGO
              <tr>
                <td>{$registro->TXT_NOMEX_PESSO}</td>
                <td>{$registro->TXT_FONEX_PESSO}</td>
                <td>{$registro->DAT_NASCI_PESSO}</td>
                <td>{$registro->TXT_EMAIL_PESSO}</td>
                <td>{$registro->FLG_USUAR_MOBIL}</td>
                <td>{$registro->FLG_STATU_PESSO}</td>
             </tr>
CODIGO;
        }
    } else {
        $html .= 'Não existe vinculo para está pessoa.';
    }                     
    $html .= <<<CODIGO
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
CODIGO;

    include("../pdf/mpdf60/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->list_number_suffix = ')';
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
```

No lugar do delimitador CODIGO você pode usar a string que achar melhor.

Veja mais sobre o HereDoc nesta postagem:

> [Para que serve <<< EOH no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14241/para-que-serve-eoh-no-php)

### Outras maneiras

Vai de gosto e do contexto, mas veja um outro modo de lidar com várias linhas:

```
$html .= '<div class="box-content no-padding table-responsive relMembros">';
$html .= '  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-heading table-datatable" id="tabMembros">';
$html .= '    <thead>';
$html .= '      <tr>';
$html .= '        <th>Nome</th>';
$html .= '        <th>Telefone</th>';
$html .= '        <th>Aniversario</th>';
$html .= '        <th>Email</th>';
$html .= '        <th>Úsuario mobile</th>';
$html .= '        <th>Status</th>';
$html .= '      </tr>';
$html .= '    </thead>';
$html .= '  <tbody>';

 ...

     foreach ($registros as $registro) {
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '  <td>' . $registro->TXT_NOMEX_PESSO . '</td>';
        $html .= '  <td>' . $registro->TXT_FONEX_PESSO . '</td>';
        $html .= '  <td>' . $registro->DAT_NASCI_PESSO . '</td>';
        $html .= '  <td>' . $registro->TXT_EMAIL_PESSO . '</td>';
        $html .= '  <td>' . $registro->FLG_USUAR_MOBIL . '</td>';
        $html .= '  <td>' . $registro->FLG_STATU_PESSO . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
```

### Formatando pra ficar simpático no HTML

Se quiser, ainda pode evitar os espaços em branco e deixar o HTML formatado usando `\t` e `\n`;

```
$html .= "\t\t<tr>\n";
$html .= "\t\t\t<th>Nome</th>\n";
$html .= "\t\t\t<th>Telefone</th>\n";
```

Sendo que os `\t` vão virar tabulações, e os `\n` quebras de linha.

Comment: SAca de mPDF também ?

Comment: Nunca usei. Eu uso o FPDF, sem a parte HTML (No FPDF vc desenha diretamente nas posições da página).

Comment: Porque ele esta abrindo o PDF na mesma página, ou seja não está interpretando o comando e sim colocando todo aquele código na tela

Comment: Ai ta faltando acertar os headers.

Comment: sabe como seria ?

Comment: `header("Content-type:application/pdf");` e se quiser forçar download `header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");` - geralmente o primeiro já basta. Lembre-se que isso é logo no começo da página, antes de qualquer dado ser enviado. Não pode ter nem espaço antes do primeiro `<?php` pra nao interferir.

Comment: é não funcionou

Comment: veja que vc esta chamando $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); duas vezes, acho meio estranho isso tb.

Comment: Vc fala que "está abrindo na mesma pagina"... Tem mais coisa na pagina alem do PDF? Não pode misturar. Ou vc serve a página pra abrir no navegador, ou faz o PDF. Tem que ser PHP separado pras duas coisas (ou ter uma lógica para mostrar só uma coisa ou só a outra).

Comment: Sim, porque faço seguinte, tenho a index, dentro da index tenho uma div chamaod content, quando clico o botão para gerar o pdf ele me redireciona via ajax para pagina onde coloco o conteúdo dentro do index.

Comment: Entao, vc tem que separar essa lógica. Ou mostra na tela, ou gera o pdf. Se quiser pode até por um link na parte que mostra na tela, mas esse link tem que chamar novamente o PHP pra gerar o PDF.

Comment: Deixa so ver como fazer isto kkkk

Comment: Pra simplificar, vc pode fazer um if( $_GET['PDF'] == 1 ) mostra na tela, e mostra o link conteudo.php?PDF=1 ELSE manda os headers, e faz o output. Assim o ajax vai chamar sem o PDF=1, entao vai sair HTML. Mas se a pessoa clicar no link, tem o ?PDF=1 que muda a lógica e só gera o PDF. Assim, a geração fica igual, mas o IF seleciona se vai HTML ou se vai PDF pro cliente.

Comment: Vou tentar implementar aqui

Comment: Boa diversão kkk. Mas se enroscar feio, lembre que vc pode fazer uma pergunta separada com o problema especifico (mas nao se esqueca de por as partes relevantes do código). Se for pra "treinar", você pode fazer uma versão só PDF, e uma só tela, pra testar, depois vc junta numa só. Ou pode usar includes. `geraconteudo.php` faz o HTML, ai o `ajax.php` faz include de `geraconteudo.php` e joga na tela, e o `pdf.php` também faz include do `geraconteudo.php`, mas faz um PDF. Assim vc separa tudo e reaproveita.

Comment: Conseguir aqui, estou abrindo um popup com o pdf

Comment: Vou ver uma forma de tratar o popup para ele abrir sempre na tela e dentro de uma caixa, verei que eu faço. Obrigado me ajudou muito