# email com tabela desconfigurada

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, email

O código abaixo envia email de confirmação de pedido corretamente, no entanto chega desconfigurado para apenas 'um único destinatário'. 
No caso, o produto no campo descrição aparece impresso antes de qualquer coisa na tela e algumas palavras aparecem juntas.
[image: Resultados do mesmo código]

```
    /* FORMATAÇÃO HTML DA MENSAGEM */
    $html ="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
            <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
            <title>Email html</title>
        </head>
        <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
            <!-- Tabela grande extrena -->
            <table border='0' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <!-- Tabela interna 1 com 600px -->
                        <table border='1' align='center' width='600px' style='border-collapse: collapse;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                            <tr><td align='center' style='padding: 30px 0 30px 0;'><img src='http://XXXXX.com/gui/Imagens/Logo_eMail.png' alt='XXXXX' width='50' height='50' style='display: block;' /></td></tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td style='padding:30px 30px 30px 30px'>
                                    <!-- Tabela mais interna-->
                                    <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                            <tr><td colspan='2'><p>Olá, ".$nome."!<br>Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso no portal da XXXXX, conforme detalhes abaixo:<br><br></p></td></tr>
                                            <tr><th colspan='2' bgcolor='#9CC6F7'>DETALHAMENTO DE PEDIDO</th></tr>
                                            <tr><td colspan='2'>PEDIDO n. : ".$numTroca."</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td colspan='2'>DESTINATÁRIO : ".$strDestin."</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td bgcolor='#9CC6F7' align='center' width='15%'><b>QTD</b></td><td bgcolor='#9CC6F7' align='center' width='85%'><b>DESCRIÇÃO</b></td></tr>";
                                            //MONTAGEM DINÂMICA DO MEIO DA TABELA
                                            foreach ($resTroca as $value){
                                                $brindeDesc = $value['bri_Desc'];
                                                $brindeQtd = $value['tro_Qtd'];
                                                $html .= "<tr><td width='15%'>".$brindeQtd."</td><td width='85%'>".$brindeDesc."</td></tr>";
                                            }
                    $html .="</table>
                             </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td><p><br>Gratos pela preferência, logo mais você receberá novo email com instruções e endereço de retirada do brinde.<br>Atenciosamente, <br>Zharium</p></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    <!-- Fim da Tabela 1 -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <!-- Fim da Tabela grande externa -->
        </body>
    </html>";


    /**FORMATANDO O ENVIO DEEMAIL*/
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SetLanguage('pt');   // Define o Idioma
    $mail->IsHTML(true);        // Enviar como HTML
    $mail->IsSMTP();            // Define que será enviado por SMTP
    $mail->CharSet   = 'utf-8'; // Define a Codificação

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;       
    $mail->Host      = 'br337.hostgator.com.br'; // Servidor SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth  = true;    // Servidor SMTP precisa de autenticação
    $mail->Username  = 'sac@XXXXXXX.com';  // E-mail para aut. no SMTP
    $mail->Password  = '*****';       // Senha do E-mail

    $mail->From      = 'sac@XXXXXX.com'; // Define o Remetente
    $mail->FromName  = 'XXXXXX';         // Nome do Remetente
    $mail->AddAddress($emailTo,$nome);    // Email e Nome do destinatário
    $mail->AddCC('XXXXXX@outlook.com','XXXXXXX'); // Envia Cópia
    $mail->WordWrap = 70;
    $mail->Subject  = $assunto;           // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Body = $html;                  // Corpo da mensagem HTML

    $enviado = $mail->Send();             // Envia o e-mail
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();          // Limpa os destinatários

    if($enviado){     // Testa o envio
      return true;
    }else{
      echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
      echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo; die();
    }
```

Comment: Esse código tem vários problemas, um deles é não escapar caracteres especiais, outro deles é que você não limpa a variável $meio antes do loop (tem mais problemas, mas esses dois já são suficientes pra ficar um inferno o debug)

Comment: Olá @Bacco, grata por sua atenção. modifiquei o código, como pode ver, mas ainda assim ele dá problemas ainda num único destinatário.
As váriáveis são iniciadas num intervalo que não está visível, portanto se puder me apontar os outros erros.. ficaria agradecida.

Comment: vc precisa  de .htmlentities( $brindeQtd ). pra cuidar de caracteres especiais (caso nao esteja fazendo isso em outra parte do código). Uma coisa que pode ajudar é usar heredoc. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14258/70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certa vez tive um problema semelhante.

Quando o html tem muitos caracteres em uma mesma linha (antes de um \r\n), alguns servidores de e-mail quebram essas linhas quando atingem o limite do buffer de string (inserem um \n) podendo invalidar o html. Por exemplo, fazendo um `<td>` virar `<t\nd>` e "bagunçando" a tabela.

É possível que o problema seja a linha concatenada dentro do loop. Talvez ela esteja muito comprida no final.

Tente concatenar um "\r\n" no final da linha em cada iteração.

```
foreach ($resTroca as $value){
    $brindeDesc = $value['bri_Desc'];
    $brindeQtd = $value['tro_Qtd'];
    $html .= "<tr><td width='15%'>".$brindeQtd."</td><td width='85%'>".$brindeDesc."</td></tr>\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Gratíssima, @Enhardned . Tentarei adicionar "\n" já que minha hospedagem é linux.

Comment: É possível que apenas o \n não funcione. Pois, como pode ser observado, o problema nao se encontra no seu servidor, mas no servidor de destino. Sendo assim, \r\n seria uma solução de maior abrangência.

Comment: Sim, @Enhardned, deu certo. Funcionou perfeitamente. O resto é acertar o texto com heredoc. Gratíssima!

Comment: Se possível, peço que marque a resposta como correta, assim ajudamos outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Perdão @Enhardned, como marco esta resposta como correta? É a primeira vez que uso o stack.. e não vejo essa opção... Cliquei na seta para cima como resposta útil, seria isso?

Comment: Segundo esse link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow , fica abaixo das seta "Está resposta é util" e "essa resposta não é util" na esquerda da resposta (um checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Fiz as alterações no código abaixo, criei uma única variável que concatena o HTML chamada $html, a cada volta no loop vai incrementando.

Obs.: Retirei o comentário, tava dando erro aqui na hora de postar o código novamente.

```
<?PHP
$html ="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
        <title>Email html</title>
    </head>
    <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <!-- Tabela grande extrena -->
        <table border='0' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <!-- Tabela interna 1 com 600px -->
                    <table border='1' align='center' width='600px' style='border-collapse: collapse;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                        <tr><td colspan='2' align='center' style='padding: 30px 0 30px 0;'><img src='http://zoiha.com.br/gui/Imagens/Logo_eMail.png' alt='Zoiha' width='50' height='50' style='display: block;' /></td></tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td style='padding:30px 30px 30px 30px'>
                                <!-- Tabela mais interna-->
                                <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                        <tr><td colspan='2'><p>Olá, ".$nome."!<br>Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso no portal da Zoiha, conforme detalhes abaixo:<br><br></p></td></tr>
                                        <tr><th colspan='2' bgcolor='#9CC6F7'>DETALHAMENTO DE PEDIDO</th></tr>
                                        <tr><td colspan='2'>PEDIDO n. : ".$numTroca."</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td colspan='2'>DESTINATÁRIO : ".$strDestin."</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td bgcolor='#9CC6F7' align='center' width='15%'><b>QTD</b></td><td bgcolor='#9CC6F7' align='center' width='85%'><b>DESCRIÇÃO</b></td></tr>";
                                        //MONTAGEM DINÂMICA DO MEIO DA TABELA
                                        foreach ($resTroca as $value){
                                            $brindeDesc = $value['bri_Desc'];
                                            $brindeQtd = $value['tro_Qtd'];
                                            $html .= "<tr><td width='15%'>".$brindeQtd."</td><td width='85%'>".$brindeDesc."</td></tr>";
                                        }
                       $html .="</table>";
                $html .="</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td><p><br>Gratos pela preferência, logo mais você receberá novo email com instruções e endereço de retirada do brinde.<br>Atenciosamente, <br>Zoiha</p></td></tr>
                    </table>
                <!-- Fim da Tabela 1 -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- Fim da Tabela grande externa -->
    </body>
</html>";

/**------FORMATANDO O ENVIO DE EMAIL -----*/
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage('pt');          // Define o Idioma
$mail->IsHTML(true);                // Enviar como HTML
$mail->IsSMTP();                       // Define que será enviado por SMTP
$mail->CharSet   = 'utf-8';         // Define a Codificação

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;            //nível de erro para depuração
$mail->Host      = 'br335.hostgator.com.br'; // Servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true;               // Caso o servidor SMTP precise de autenticação
$mail->Username  = 'sac@zoiha.com.br';  // Usuário ou E-mail para autenticação no SMTP
$mail->Password  = '1234567890';       // Senha do E-mail

$mail->From      = 'sac@zoiha.com.br'; // Define o Remetente
$mail->FromName  = 'Zoiha';         // Nome do Remetente
$mail->AddAddress($emailTo,$nome);    // Email e Nome do destinatário
$mail->AddCC('zoiha5@outlook.com','Zoiha'); // Envia Cópia
$mail->WordWrap = 70;
$mail->Subject  = $assunto;           // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = $html;                  // Corpo da mensagem em formato HTML

$enviado = $mail->Send();             // Envia o e-mail
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();          // Limpa os destinatários

if($enviado){ // Testa o envio
            return true;

}else{
            echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
            echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo; die();
}
```

Comment: Grata @Coringa. Fiz as correções mas continua dando o mesmo erro para "um determinado destinatário" (curiosamente um destinatário '.net'). O código é perfeito em qualquer email, mas nesse email a 2a 'TD' da linha dinâmica (a de DESCRIÇÃO) se comporta como se não tivesse sido fechada. Assim, a descrição dos produtos fica fora da célula. Fiz o teste com 2 produtos, Ele me retornou um produto dentro da célula QTD e o outro fora da tabela mais interna. Gostaria de mandar uma imagem ta tela aqui, mas não sei como faço isso. Tenho tentado há dias uma solução sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Na tabela interna 1, no primeiro `<td>`, está declarando `colspan=2` sem necessidade.

Alguns renderizadores podem interpretar de forma literal e outros apenas ignoram.

Quando é interpretado literalmente, a renderização adiciona células que não existem, causando o efeito visual indesejado.

Experimente remover o atributo `colspan` das células onde se faz desnecessário.

Uma terceira causa pode ser o conteúdo estar sendo dividido. Sistemas mais antigos impõem limitações de quantidade de caracteres por linha num arquivo texto.

Veja um exemplo do que acontece quando o conteúdo texto é dividido: https://ideone.com/37fzHa

Esse teste foi reproduzido usando a função do PHP [chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' '
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
<html>
    <head>
       
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf
-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0'/>
        <title>Email html</title>
    </hea
d>
    <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <!-- Tabela
 grande extrena -->
        <table border='0' width='100%' cellp
adding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
                <td
>
                <!-- Tabela interna 1 com 600px -->
          
          <table border='1' align='center' width='600px' style='
border-collapse: collapse;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
   
                     <tr><td colspan='2' align='center' style='p
adding: 30px 0 30px 0;'><img src='http://zoiha.com.br/gui/Imagen
s/Logo_eMail.png' alt='Zoiha' width='50' height='50' style='disp
lay: block;' /></td></tr>
                         <tr>
        
                    <td style='padding:30px 30px 30px 30px'>
   
                             <!-- Tabela mais interna-->
       
                         <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cells
pacing='0' width='100%'>
                                       
 <tr><td colspan='2'><p>Olá, foo!<br>Seu pedido foi realizado c
om sucesso no portal da Zoiha, conforme detalhes abaixo:<br><br>
</p></td></tr>
                                        <tr><th c
olspan='2' bgcolor='#9CC6F7'>DETALHAMENTO DE PEDIDO</th></tr>
  
                                      <tr><td colspan='2'>PEDIDO
 n. : foo 1</td></tr>
                                        <t
r><td colspan='2'>DESTINATÁRIO : foo 2</td></tr>
              
                          <tr><td bgcolor='#9CC6F7' align='cente
r' width='15%'><b>QTD</b></td><td bgcolor='#9CC6F7' align='cente
r' width='85%'><b>DESCRIÇÃO</b></td></tr><tr><td width='15%'>1
</td><td width='85%'>test 1</td></tr><tr><td width='15%'>1</td><
td width='85%'>test 2</td></tr><tr><td width='15%'>1</td><td wid
th='85%'>test 2</td></tr></table></td>
                        <
/tr>
                        <tr><td><p><br>Gratos pela preferê
ncia, logo mais você receberá novo email com instruções e en
dereço de retirada do brinde.<br>Atenciosamente, <br>Zoiha</p><
/td></tr>
                    </table>
                <!-- Fim 
da Tabela 1 -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        
</table>
    <!-- Fim da Tabela grande externa -->
    </body>
<
/html>
```

Para sanar a dúvida em relação ao conteúdo dividido (chunk split), se possível pegue o e-mail original e leia o código original recebido pelo servidor, (no seu caso o UOL). Precisa abrir e ler o código original da mensagem. Mas não sei dizer se o webmail do referido provedor possui tal opção.

Além bo chunk_split, outros formatos também podem corromper a renderização caso não esteja bem formatado.

É também comum que os emails sejam codificados como quoted-rpintable

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.=
w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>=0A<html>=0A    <head>=0A        <meta http-equi=
v=3D'Content-Type' content=3D'text/html; charset=3Dutf-8'>=0A        <meta =
name=3D'viewport' content=3D'width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=3D1.0'/>=
=0A        <title>Email html</title>=0A    </head>=0A    <body style=3D'mar=
gin: 0; padding: 0;'>=0A        <!-- Tabela grande extrena -->=0A        <t=
able border=3D'0' width=3D'100%' cellpadding=3D'0' cellspacing=3D'0'>=0A   =
         <tr>=0A                <td>=0A                <!-- Tabela interna =
1 com 600px -->=0A                    <table border=3D'1' align=3D'center' =
width=3D'600px' style=3D'border-collapse: collapse;' cellpadding=3D'0' cell=
spacing=3D'0'>=0A                        <tr><td colspan=3D'2' align=3D'cen=
ter' style=3D'padding: 30px 0 30px 0;'><img src=3D'http://zoiha.com.br/gui/=
Imagens/Logo_eMail.png' alt=3D'Zoiha' width=3D'50' height=3D'50' style=3D'd=
isplay: block;' /></td></tr>=0A                         <tr>=0A            =
                <td style=3D'padding:30px 30px 30px 30px'>=0A              =
                  <!-- Tabela mais interna-->=0A                           =
     <table border=3D'1' cellpadding=3D'0' cellspacing=3D'0' width=3D'100%'=
>=0A                                        <tr><td colspan=3D'2'><p>Ol=
=C3=A1, foo!<br>Seu pedido foi realizado com sucesso no portal da Zoiha, co=
nforme detalhes abaixo:<br><br></p></td></tr>=0A                           =
             <tr><th colspan=3D'2' bgcolor=3D'#9CC6F7'>DETALHAMENTO DE PEDI=
DO</th></tr>=0A                                        <tr><td colspan=3D'2=
'>PEDIDO n. : foo 1</td></tr>=0A                                        <tr=
><td colspan=3D'2'>DESTINAT=C3=81RIO : foo 2</td></tr>=0A                  =
                      <tr><td bgcolor=3D'#9CC6F7' align=3D'center' width=3D=
'15%'><b>QTD</b></td><td bgcolor=3D'#9CC6F7' align=3D'center' width=3D'85%'=
><b>DESCRI=C3=87=C3=83O</b></td></tr><tr><td width=3D'15%'>1</td><td width=
=3D'85%'>test 1</td></tr><tr><td width=3D'15%'>1</td><td width=3D'85%'>test=
 2</td></tr><tr><td width=3D'15%'>1</td><td width=3D'85%'>test 2</td></tr><=
/table></td>=0A                        </tr>=0A                        <tr>=
<td><p><br>Gratos pela prefer=C3=AAncia, logo mais voc=C3=AA receber=C3=
=A1 novo email com instru=C3=A7=C3=B5es e endere=C3=A7o de retirada do brin=
de.<br>Atenciosamente, <br>Zoiha</p></td></tr>=0A                    </tabl=
e>=0A                <!-- Fim da Tabela 1 -->=0A                </td>=0A   =
         </tr>=0A        </table>=0A    <!-- Fim da Tabela grande externa -=
->=0A    </body>=0A</html>
```

Aqui no snippet você vai ver um resultado estanho nas letras como `=0A=0A =0A =0A = =0A =0A =0A =0A =0A =0A = =0A =0A =0A =0A =0A =0A =` mas num cliente de email é exibido corretamente pois é feito o decode automaticamente. On importante aqui que quero mostrar é como a formatação da sua tabela também quebra com esse formato. Veja o resultado visual no snippet.

## Resumindo

Nas configurações da instância do PHPMailer, defina o parâmetro Encoding como base64 ou quoted-printable. Exemplo:

```
$mail->Encoding = "base64"
```

ou

```
$mail->Encoding = "quoted-printable"
```

Experimente também reduzir o parâmetro WordWrap. Normalmente acima de 64 provoca problemas de formatação. Portanto um valor mais seguro é 50.

```
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
```

## Corrija a semântica HTML

Conforme explicado anteriormente, há um uso desnecessário de colspan.

Remova todos os atributos colspan do código e mantenha somente nesse trecho

```
<tr><th colspan='2' bgcolor='#9CC6F7'>DETALHAMENTO DE PEDIDO</th></tr>
```

Todos os outros, pode apagar.

Comment: Olá @Daniel Omine, grata por sua atenção. Eu corrigi isso, mas ainda continua com o mesmo erro (lembrando que este erro é em um único servidor de email.. UOL). Refiz todo o código e as variáveis são inicializadas antes desta parte visível ai no código, mas... sem sucesso.

Comment: Acredito que o problema maior seja a semântica HTML com o uso errôneo do colspan e também a quantidade de caracteres por linha. Está definido como 70 o limite mas normalmente 64 é o recomendado. Adicionei mais algumas infromações na resposta. Se quiser leia somente o trecho final "Resumindo" e "Corrija a semântica HTML". Acredito que seguindo essas instruções poderá resolver o problema.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, no entanto seguirei suas recomendações para melhores práticas.