# Erro de leitura de código HTML na função Mail.php

Tags: php, html, envio-de-email

Então, criei um formulário de contato do qual precisaria que ele viesse bem formatado no e-mail destinatário. Por isso deixei o HTML um pouco mais estruturado e utilizei CSS Inline para as configurações, conforme ditam as boas práticas para envio de HTML por e-mail.

Armazenei todo o código abaixo dentro de uma variável (da qual eu utilizo-a depois na função mail para o corpo da mensagem):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
h2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>

<body>
<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">1. Dados Pessoais</h2></caption>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><strong>Nome:</strong> $nome </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Estado Civil:</strong> $estadoCivil</td><td><strong>Resid.:</strong> $telefoneFixo</td><td><strong>Cel.:</strong> $telefoneCelular</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Sexo:</strong> $sexo </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoPessoal <td><strong>Naturalidade:</strong> $naturalidade </td>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><strong>Endereço:</strong> $endereco</td></tr></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Bairro:</strong> $bairro </td><td><strong>CEP:</strong> $cep </td><td><strong>Cidade:</strong> $cidade </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Nome do Pai:</strong> $nomePai </td><td><strong>Nome da Mãe:</strong> $nomeMae </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Gru de Instrução:</strong> $grauInstrucao </td><td><strong>Completo?</strong> $grauCompleto </td><td><strong>Raça/Cor:</strong> $racaCor</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">2. Beneficiários</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>Cônjuge:</strong> $conjuge </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoConjuge </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfConjuge </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep1 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep1 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep1 </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep2 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep2 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep2 </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep3 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep3 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep3 </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep4 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep4 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep3 </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">3. Documentação</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>RG:</strong> $rg </td><td><strong>Orgão Exp.:</strong> $orgaoExpedidor </td><td><strong>Data de Exp.:</strong> $dataexpedicaoRG </td><td><strong>CPF:</strong> $cpf </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Título de Eleitor:</strong> $tituloEleitor </td><td><strong>Zona:</strong> $zonaEleitor </td><td><strong>Seção:</strong> $secaoEleitor</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>CTPS:</strong> $ctps </td><td><strong>Série:</strong> $serieCTPS </td><td><strong>UF:</strong> $ufCTPS </td><td><strong>Data de Exp.:</strong> $dataexpedicaoCTPS </td><td><strong>PIS:</strong> $pis </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Carteira de Hab.:</strong> $carteiraHabilitacao </td><td><strong>Categoria:</strong> $categoriaHab </td><td><strong>Vencimento:</strong> $vencimentoHab</td><td><strong>UF:</strong> $ufHab </td><td><strong>Reservista:</strong> $reservista</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">4. Dados Bancários</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>Banco:</strong> $nomeBanco </td> <td><strong>Agência:</strong> $agenciaBanco </td><td><strong>Conta:</strong> $contaBanco </td></tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">5. Benefícios</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>Vale Transporte:</strong> $valeTransporte </td><td><strong>Qtde por dia:</strong> $qtdeVT </td><td><strong>Valor da Tarifa:</strong> $valorVT </td><td><strong>Empresa:</strong> $empres </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><strong>Número Cartão Transporte/SIC:</strong> $numeroTransporte </td></tr>     
            <tr><td><strong>Vale Alimentação:</strong> $valeAlimentacao </td><td><strong>Vale Refeição:</strong> $valeRefeicao </td><td><strong>Valor por Dia:</strong> $valorDia </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">6. Informações Adicionais</h2></caption>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Centro de Custo:</strong> $centroCusto</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Já trabalhou nesta empresa:</strong> $jaTrabalhou</td> <td><strong>Contrato de Experiência:</strong> $contratoExp</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Período de Experiência:</strong> $periodoExp</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Sindicato:</strong> $sindicato</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Forma de Contratação:</strong> $formaContratacao</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Cargo e Funação: </strong>$cargoFuncao </td> <td><strong>Data de Início: </strong>$dataInicio</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Horário de Trabalho: </strong>$horarioTrabalho </td> <td><strong>Intervalo: </strong>$intervalo</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Sábado: </strong>$sabado </td> <td><strong>Horário: </strong>$horarioSabado </td> <td><strong>Qtde Sábados Mês: </strong>$qtdeSabado</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Salário: </strong>$salario </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Já realizou contribuição sindical este ano? </strong>$contrSindical</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Insalubridade: </strong>$insalubridade</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Crachá: </strong>$cracha</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" width="790">
    <tfooter align="center" width="790">        
    <tr><td align="center">$data</td></tr>
    </tfooter>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Defini os headers corretamente para indicar as configurações do corpo da mensagem:

```
   $headers = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Entretanto, ao enviar o formulário, ele não está reconhecendo as configurações do HTML.

Ele fica acusando erros como (no caso do witdh="790" da tabela):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '790' (T_LNUMBER)
```

E consequentemente ele acusa erro em todas as outras configurações inline, como o valor do width, align, colspan, etc.

Alguém sabe porque isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Não da pra saber exatamente pq não tem atribuição da variável na pergunta mas desconfio que tenha um aspa dupla antes e `width="` é interpretado como o fechamento.

Comment: Provavelmente é o que o @rray comentou, quando tenho de enviar e-mail dessa deixo o html em arquivo _.html_ e carrego o arquivo com `file_get_contents` e dou um `replace` nas variáveis. Tipo o `$data` estaria assim `<tr><td align="center">@data@</td></tr>`.

Comment: Quando vai armazenar o HTML na variável, como está fazendo?

Comment: Era exatamente isso @rray  acabei não me atentando. O erro ocorre porque está sendo interpretado o fechamento da variável mesmo.

Quais seriam as alternativas viáveis para essa situação? Não compreendi muito bem a sugestão do fernandoandrade (Sou iniciante ainda).

Comment: @caiocafardo $mensagem = "meu html";

Comment: Pode usar o heredoc para montar um template [veja nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14258/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça a atribuição da variável assim:

```
$var = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
h2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>

<body>
<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">1. Dados Pessoais</h2></caption>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><strong>Nome:</strong> $nome </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Estado Civil:</strong> $estadoCivil</td><td><strong>Resid.:</strong> $telefoneFixo</td><td><strong>Cel.:</strong> $telefoneCelular</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Sexo:</strong> $sexo </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoPessoal <td><strong>Naturalidade:</strong> $naturalidade </td>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><strong>Endereço:</strong> $endereco</td></tr></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Bairro:</strong> $bairro </td><td><strong>CEP:</strong> $cep </td><td><strong>Cidade:</strong> $cidade </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Nome do Pai:</strong> $nomePai </td><td><strong>Nome da Mãe:</strong> $nomeMae </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Gru de Instrução:</strong> $grauInstrucao </td><td><strong>Completo?</strong> $grauCompleto </td><td><strong>Raça/Cor:</strong> $racaCor</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">2. Beneficiários</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>Cônjuge:</strong> $conjuge </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoConjuge </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfConjuge </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep1 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep1 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep1 </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep2 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep2 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep2 </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep3 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep3 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep3 </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Dependente:</strong> $dep4 </td><td><strong>Nascimento:</strong> $datanascimentoDep4 </td><td><strong>IRRF:</strong> $irrfDep3 </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">3. Documentação</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>RG:</strong> $rg </td><td><strong>Orgão Exp.:</strong> $orgaoExpedidor </td><td><strong>Data de Exp.:</strong> $dataexpedicaoRG </td><td><strong>CPF:</strong> $cpf </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Título de Eleitor:</strong> $tituloEleitor </td><td><strong>Zona:</strong> $zonaEleitor </td><td><strong>Seção:</strong> $secaoEleitor</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>CTPS:</strong> $ctps </td><td><strong>Série:</strong> $serieCTPS </td><td><strong>UF:</strong> $ufCTPS </td><td><strong>Data de Exp.:</strong> $dataexpedicaoCTPS </td><td><strong>PIS:</strong> $pis </td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Carteira de Hab.:</strong> $carteiraHabilitacao </td><td><strong>Categoria:</strong> $categoriaHab </td><td><strong>Vencimento:</strong> $vencimentoHab</td><td><strong>UF:</strong> $ufHab </td><td><strong>Reservista:</strong> $reservista</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">4. Dados Bancários</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>Banco:</strong> $nomeBanco </td> <td><strong>Agência:</strong> $agenciaBanco </td><td><strong>Conta:</strong> $contaBanco </td></tr>            
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">5. Benefícios</h2></caption>
            <tr><td><strong>Vale Transporte:</strong> $valeTransporte </td><td><strong>Qtde por dia:</strong> $qtdeVT </td><td><strong>Valor da Tarifa:</strong> $valorVT </td><td><strong>Empresa:</strong> $empres </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><strong>Número Cartão Transporte/SIC:</strong> $numeroTransporte </td></tr>     
            <tr><td><strong>Vale Alimentação:</strong> $valeAlimentacao </td><td><strong>Vale Refeição:</strong> $valeRefeicao </td><td><strong>Valor por Dia:</strong> $valorDia </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="790" align="center">
    <tbody align="center" width="790">
            <caption><h2 align="left">6. Informações Adicionais</h2></caption>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Centro de Custo:</strong> $centroCusto</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Já trabalhou nesta empresa:</strong> $jaTrabalhou</td> <td><strong>Contrato de Experiência:</strong> $contratoExp</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Período de Experiência:</strong> $periodoExp</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Sindicato:</strong> $sindicato</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Forma de Contratação:</strong> $formaContratacao</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Cargo e Funação: </strong>$cargoFuncao </td> <td><strong>Data de Início: </strong>$dataInicio</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Horário de Trabalho: </strong>$horarioTrabalho </td> <td><strong>Intervalo: </strong>$intervalo</td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Sábado: </strong>$sabado </td> <td><strong>Horário: </strong>$horarioSabado </td> <td><strong>Qtde Sábados Mês: </strong>$qtdeSabado</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Salário: </strong>$salario </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Já realizou contribuição sindical este ano? </strong>$contrSindical</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Insalubridade: </strong>$insalubridade</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Crachá: </strong>$cracha</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" width="790">
    <tfooter align="center" width="790">        
    <tr><td align="center">$data</td></tr>
    </tfooter>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
```

quando utilizamos aspas duplas no html, o php permite utilizar na definição de string as aspas simples.

Comment: Interessante @NIZZOLA, não sabia dessa possibilidade, resolveu meu problema, o formulário agora não da mais erro!

Entretanto, no e-mail ele não está imprimindo o valor da variável e sim a variável em si. Por exemplo: "Nome: $nome". Devo mudar algo na sintaxe por usar as aspas simples?

Comment: Quando utiliza aspas simples variáveis não são interpretadas.

Comment: Faça a concatenação das variáveis assim: $nome = 'abde' . $var .'fghij'; ou a inversão das aspas duplas pelas simples assim $nome = "abde $var tags html assim <input type='text'>";

Comment: @NIZZOLA desculpa minha ignorância, mas não compreendi muito bem como fazer esse procedimento que você sugeriu.

A concatenação deve ser feita no momento da declaração das variáveis ou no momento de declaração delas no início?

Se você puder mostrar com 1 linha do código que montei como deveria ficar a sintaxe acho que facilitaria minha compreensão.

Caso necessite, segue como declarei algumas varíaveis:
nome = $_POST['nome'];
$estadoCivil = $_POST['estado-civil'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$telefoneFixo = $_POST['tel'];
$telefoneCelular = $_POST['cel'];

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel Eu já precisei fazer isso e há duas formas, você coloca num bloco de notas seu html e substitui todas as apas duplas por simples assim poderá usar no php as aspas duplas como delimitadores. exemplo: $var = " <input type='text'>";   veja que as apas simples estarão fazendo o papel no html normal e aí você pode colocar variáveis dentro. Uma outra forma é concatenar a string você termina a string onde a variavel entra e depois continua. exemplo : $var = 'xyz'.$var2.'abdde'; sem mexer no seu código html.

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel por favor, verificar e colocar a pergunta como respondida.

Comment: @NIZZOLA me desculpa, é que sou novo no portal, não consegui achar onde colocar a pergunta como respondida? Não era só assinalar a aceitação da resposta na sua resposta com códigos?