# Erro em Slider HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Olá! Tenho um slider em HTML e estou implantando PHP para torná-lo gerenciável, todavia, ao colocar o PHP, o slider parou de funcionar. Acredito que seja um erro na parte a seguir do código:

```
                echo '<div class="col-md-12" style="top:15px;">';
            echo '<div class="lightbox" data-plugin-options=".{"delegate":"a","gallery":{"enabled":true,"tPrev":"Anterior","tNext":"Pr\u00f3ximo"},"image":{"verticalFit":false}}.">';
            echo '<div class="owl-carousel text-center controlls-over" data-plugin-options=".{"items":1,"singleItem":true,"lazyLoad":true,"navigation":true,"pagination":false,"transitionStyle":"fadeUp","autoHeight":true,"autoPlay":false}.">';
            echo '<div class="item">';
```

Acredito que a concatenação esteja errada. O que fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema aí é uma mistura de aspas na parte HTML mesmo.

Uma maneira mais simples é fechar o PHP para cair no modo HTML puro, assim você pode usar aspas duplas e simples para separar os parâmetros em HTML dos objetos em JS:

```
<?php
   // ... resto do codigo ...
?>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="top:15px;">
    <div class="lightbox" data-plugin-options="{'delegate':'a','gallery':'enabled':true,'tPrev':'Anterior','tNext':'Pr\u00f3ximo'},'image':{'verticalFit':false}}">
    <div class="owl-carousel text-center controlls-over" data-plugin-options="{'items':1,'singleItem':true,'lazyLoad':true,'navigation':true,'pagination':false,'transitionStyle':'fadeUp','autoHeight':true,'autoPlay':false}">
    <div class="item">
<?php
   // ... resto do codigo ...
?>
```

Outra é usar `HEREDOC`, se quiser futuramente usar variáveis do PHP sem precisar de `echo`:

```
echo <<<HTML
<div class="col-md-12" style="top:15px;">
<div class="lightbox" data-plugin-options="{'delegate':'a','gallery':'enabled':true,'tPrev':'Anterior','tNext':'Pr\u00f3ximo'},'image':{'verticalFit':false}}">
<div class="owl-carousel text-center controlls-over" data-plugin-options="{'items':1,'singleItem':true,'lazyLoad':true,'navigation':true,'pagination':false,'transitionStyle':'fadeUp','autoHeight':true,'autoPlay':false}">
<div class="item">
HTML;
```

Mais detalhes sobre `HEREDOC` aqui:

> [Para que serve <<< EOH no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14241/70)