# Me ajude a escrever este código corretamente

Tags: php, html

O seguinte código faz parte de um script php que estou desenvolvendo, ele funciona, mas eu sinto como se eu estivesse escrevendo uma gambiarra por causa do posicionamento das aspas e aspas duplas. Podem me dizer se posso deixar o código assim mesmo?

```
print '<div class="titleebay"><a rel="nofollow" href="'. $product['link_produto'] . '">"' . $product['nome'] . '"</a></div>';
print '<div class="mainproduct"><a rel="nofollow" href="' . $product['link_produto'] . '"><img style="height:120px" src="' . $product['link_imagem'] . '"/><br/>';
//print "De:;&nbspR$". $preco_normal . "<br/>";
print '<span>Apenas&nbspR$"' . $product['preco_promocao'] . '"<br/></a></span></div>';
//print "Em&nbsp" . $parcelas . "x de&nbsp:&nbspR$" . $vl_parcelas . "</a></span></div>";
```

}

Comment: Pode usar o `printf()` ou [here/nowdoc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14241/91) no lugar desses prints.

Comment: Não existe "dislike" no stackoveflow, e sim downvotes. E eles geralmente apontam qualidade ruim nas perguntas, falta de mais informações sobre o problema ou falta de clareza.

Comment: [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Grandes diferenças cara, tipo trocar satanás por lúcifer. A pergunta está bem clara. ¬¬'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o que sempre costumo fazer e usar o HTML com PHP e nao o PHP com HTML, ou seja.

```
<div class="titleebay">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="<?= $product['link_produto']  ?>"><?= $product['nome'] ?></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode enviar o produto para view em formato de objeto, fica mais fácil de você trabalhar.
Adaptado o seu código eu faria algo assim:

```
$productObj = (object) $product;
print("<div class='titleebay'><a rel='nofollow' href='$productObj->link_produto'>$productObj->nome</a></div>");
```