# Concatenar variável em array

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho que requisitar um `json` para uma `api`, porém tenho que resgatar dados de um formulário para complementar esse `json`, o problema é que ao resgatar os dados para dentro de uma variável não consigo colocá-la da maneira correta dentro desse `json`, tentei concatenar de diversas formas e o valor nunca é passado corretamente.

```
$str = '{
    "clienteLogin": 
    {
        "Token":"29b3bcbde41b48058bf410da09910849",
        "Operador":"",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio":8,
        "PalavraCaptcha":"",
        "nome": "$nome", //variavel 1
        "cadastro":"on",
        "Email": "$email" // variavel 2
    },
        "mesclarCarrinho":true,
        "Token":"29b3bcbde41b48058bf410da09910849",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio":8,
        "Operador":""

    }';
```

Comment: Essa array vem de onde? estás tu a montar com strings em PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usa aspas simples para concactnar você deve usar o ponto:

```
$var = 'variavel';

echo 'foo ' . $var . ' bar';
```

Que irá resultar em:

> ```
> foo variavel bar
> ```

Então o seu código deveria ficar assim:

```
$str = '{
    "clienteLogin": 
    {
        "Token":"29b3bcbde41b48058bf410da09910849",
        "Operador":"",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio":8,
        "PalavraCaptcha":"",
        "nome": "' . $nome . '", //variavel 1
        "cadastro":"on",
        "Email": "' . $email . '" // variavel 2
    },
        "mesclarCarrinho":true,
        "Token":"29b3bcbde41b48058bf410da09910849",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio":8,
        "Operador":""

    }';
```

No entanto você pode experimentar o Heredoc, como nesta [resposta do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14258/3635), seu código ficaria assim:

> MEUJSON é opcional, pode trocar por qualquer nome, é só pra facilitar mesmo

```
$texto = <<<MEUJSON
{
    "clienteLogin": 
    {
        "Token":"29b3bcbde41b48058bf410da09910849",
        "Operador":"",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio":8,
        "PalavraCaptcha":"",
        "nome": "$nome", //variavel 1
        "cadastro":"on",
        "Email": "$email" // variavel 2
    },
        "mesclarCarrinho":true,
        "Token":"29b3bcbde41b48058bf410da09910849",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio":8,
        "Operador":""

    }
MEUJSON;
```

[Exemplo no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/zHw6WE)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode transformar seu `json` em `array`, adicionar o que quiser e depois converter para `json` novamente.

```
$jsonData = json_decode($json, true);
$jsonData['clienteLogin']['email'] = $email;
$jsonData['clienteLogin']['nome'] = $nome;

$completeData = json_encode($jsonData);
```

Ou pode utilizar algumas funções de array como no exemplo:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($json, true);
$complete = array_merge($jsonData['clienteLogin'], ['nome' => $nome, 'email' => $email]);
$newJson = json_encode($complete);
```