# Separar corpo do email de dentro da tag do php

Tags: php, email

Estou querendo separar as aspa simples da tag do PHP:

Tenho um código que envia um e-mail para clientes. Vou colocar aqui apenas a parte do codigo onde quero separar as aspas simples que é essa aqui original: `$mail->Body = 'aqui';`

O que estou querendo e mais ou menos isso abaixo mais não dando certo alguém ai pra dar uma forca?

```
<?php $mail->Body = "'";?>

aqui

<?php"'";?>
```

codigo completo

```
<?php

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na mesma pasta do arquivo php
include "PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php";



// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Método de envio
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Enviar por SMTP 
$mail->Host = "mail.servidor.com.br"; // Você pode alterar este parametro para o endereço de SMTP do seu provedor
$mail->Port = 25; 

$mail->SMTPAuth = false; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório)
$mail->Username = 'username@servidor.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
//$mail->Password = 'XXXXX'; // Mesma senha da sua conta de email

// Configurações de compatibilidade para autenticação em TLS
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
 'ssl' => array(
 'verify_peer' => false,
 'verify_peer_name' => false,
 'allow_self_signed' => true
 )
);
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Você pode habilitar esta opção caso tenha problemas. Assim pode identificar mensagens de erro.

// Define o remetente
$mail->From = $_REQUEST['email']; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = $_REQUEST['Nome']; // Seu nome

// Define o(s) destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress('reservas@servidor.com.br', 'Terminal Ajato');
//$mail->AddAddress('john@doe.com');


// CC
//$mail->AddCC('me@servidor.com', ''); 

// BCC - Cópia oculta
//$mail->AddBCC('he@servidor.com', 'Roberto'); 

// Definir se o e-mail é em formato HTML ou texto plano
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Formato HTML . Use "false" para enviar em formato texto simples.

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset (opcional)

// Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Subject = $_REQUEST['Nome']; 

// Corpo do email
$mail->Body = 'aqui';


// Anexos (opcional)
//$mail->AddAttachment("/home/usuario/public_html/documento.pdf", "documento.pdf"); 

// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();


// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado


?>
```

Comment: Bem confuso sua pergunta. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: Anderson meu amigo  e que o seguinte quero fazer uma tabela no Dreamweaver na parte do corpo do email e nao estou sabendo fazer vou colocar o codigo completo abaixo pode ser ? pra vc entender melhor !

Comment: Se entendi bem, o que você precisa é [*Heredoc* ou *Nowdoc*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14241/5878). Leia sobre. E, por favor, o *snippet* é para códigos HTML/JS/CSS, não utilize-o para PHP.

Comment: Blz Obrigado meu amigo  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas acredito que o que você queira fazer é colocar um código html na variavel que corresponde ao corpo do email.

Para isso você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php $mail->Body = "<p>Primeiro paragrafo</p>";?>
```

Você pode colocar qualquer tag que ela será interpretada, caso você precise colocar aspas duplas dentro do texto use o \ antes das aspas.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php $mail->Body = "<p>Primeiro paragrafo. \" isso é apenas um teste \"</p>";?>
```

Comment: Você vai me entender agora! dentro dessas aspas duplas onde vc colocou paragrafo e a mensagem  preciso colocar outros código php com a tag <?php ;?>

Comment: Sei que esta errado é com se fosse assim: <?php $mail->Body = "<?php echo$ dados ?>";?>

Comment: Você pode concatenar o que você precisa. Dessa forma: $var = 112;  
$teste = "<p>Teste</p>". $var."Teste";

Comment: Você quer enviar um script no email? O que exatamente você quer fazer abrindo outra tag php?

Comment: Anderson so mais uma duvida seria possivel de outra forma que nao seja concatenar estou com o codigo aqui da tabela tudo pronto aqui para ser inserido

Comment: isso @MaxRogério

Comment: Mas tem a intenção de que esse script enviado seja executado ao cliente abrir o email?

Comment: nao e poque estou pegando dados de uma outra  variavel e o codigo esta prontinho nao quero concatenar

Comment: Se os dados que você precisa esta em uma variavel, você pode colocar o texto que você quer normalmente e concatenar com essa variavel que vai ser interpretado também