# Identação PHP no HTML

Tags: php, html

Bom, gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de identar o PHP junto com o HTML.
Por exemplo, meu código esta assim:

```
<h1>Como identar código PHP no HTML?</h1>
<div>
    <?php
        echo "<p>
            <a href=\"#\">Testando</a>
        <p/>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Só que quando eu executo a página no navegador ela fica assim:

```
<h1>Como identar código PHP no HTML?</h1>
<div>
    <p>
            <a href="#">Testando</a>
        <p/></div>
```

Existe uma maneira de identar a exibição do PHP no HTML?

Comment: use sintaxe alternativa nesses casos: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Primeiro que não tem sentido indentar PHP dentro de HTML, a indentação do PHP deve ser em relação ao próprio PHP (ou seja, seu primeiro código está mal indentado). E pro HTML sair certinho basta colocar a indentação no echo. Exemplo: `echo "\t\t\t<p>estou indentado</p>\n";` - Tres tabs e uma quebra de linha no HTML (tem um monte de maneiras. Para trechos grandes pode ter [HEREDOC e NOWDOC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14241/70) em vez do echo, por exemplo).

Comment: @Bacco Dependendo do caso (pq esse código do autor provavelmente nem é esse da pergunta) provavelmente irá resolver melhor usando  só `<a href="<?="variavel ou algo aqui";?>"><?="variavel ou algo aqui";?></a>` e deixar a identação no proprio HTML

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento exemplo artificial dá nisso, não dá pra saber nem qual é o problema de fato que tem que resolver (mas seja como for, indentar o trecho PHP pelo HTML nunca tem sentido)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Eu te entendo

É frustrante ver nosso código todo bagunçado, :D

**Precisa de endentação na saída do HTML?**

Na verdade não precisa.

**Faz alguma diferença para a execução do código?**

Cara se você se preocupa com cada bit que será executado, então precisará se preocupar com os espaços em branco.
Ou caso tenha uma execução muito grande, pesará no processamento.

**Alguém vai ver esse código lindo?**

Se olhar o código fonte... Sim!

**Fica bonito?**

Se você se importa com a apresentação do código, vai ficar bonito!

**Algum ponto positivo?**

- Você vai se sentir bem por ter um HTML fácil de ler e sem aquela ZONA de código salsichão.
- Quando alguém for olhar seu código vai ver que você se preocupou com isso e perceberá que se você se preocupa até com isso para quando alguém for olhar, então vai se preocupar com coisas mais importantes.
- Recrutadores costumam olhar a saída do código para ver se o profissional é organizado.

Eu sei como você deve se sentir. Sem mais delongas.

Você pode usar o [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Eu quando quero uma saída organizada do meu HTML que será escrito pelo PHP faço assim:

```php
<?php
echo <<<'HTML_EXEMPLO_PODE_SER_QUALQUER_NOME_AQUI'
    
    <h1> Precisa Olhar como ficou no comsole do Chrome </h1>
    <br>
        <p>
            <a href="#">Testando</a>
        <p/>
    <br>
            bem aqui, nessa posição, sem bagunça
HTML_EXEMPLO_PODE_SER_QUALQUER_NOME_AQUI;
?>
```

Para ver um exemplo funcionando online acesse o link a seguir e clique no botão executar código, é o mesmo código que eu coloquei acima.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d0a80bbca28482554af71f877fe643c21b0ea76

Answer (score 1):

Não dá muito não, você tem que escolher que se vai deixar mais certo o código que você lida todo dia, ou o código que vai para o navegador que você nunca lida. Se quiser fazer o segundo pode fazer algo assim:

```
<h1>Como identar código PHP no HTML?</h1>
<div>
    <?php
        echo "<p>
        <a href=\"#\">Testando</a>
    <p/>";
    ?>

</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Indent.html).

Também pode colocar PHP só onde precisa mesmo, nesse caso nem coloca porque não há código PHP real aí. Eu entendo que é só um exemplo artificial, mas só com exemplos reais é que podemos tomar decisões corretas. Cada situação pode pedir uma outra forma de fazer.

Esse caso a solução é não usar PHP, mas se for usar então coloque a *tag* só no ponto específico onde tem código. Não use `echo` para escrever blocos inteiros, só um trecho bem específico. Ou use só `echo` para tudo, e esqueça o gabarito HTML (não estou recomendando, mas é uma forma de fazer).

E leia o comentário do Bacco que faz sentido. está misturando as indentações.

Comment: Fora que ele poderia apenas usar short tag ... <?="<p><a href=\"#\">Testando</a> <p/>";?>