# Para que servem as chavetas {} numa string SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Para que servem as chavetas `{}` na seguinte string SQL usada em PHP para MySQL?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$placeholders})"
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4665/91

Comment: No seu caso ele vai substituir as chaves e o que tem dentro delas pelo valor da variável. Se não tivesse as chaves ele iria interpretar `$fields` como uma simples `string`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Chaves `{}` seguidas de um cifrão `$` indicam que a [sintaxe complexa](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) de interpolação de string está sendo usada, ela serve para invocar métodos de um objeto. Também serve para exibir o valor de uma variável(um pouco exagerado ou necessário em um caso bem particular) isso tudo só é valido dentro de aspas duplas. Membros estáticos **NÃO** podem ser invocados dentro de aspas duplas nesse caso é obrigatório fazer a concatenação das strings

```
<?php
class Pessoa {
    const FOO = 'algum valor';

    public $nome = 'mario';
    public $idade = '20';
    public static $planeta = 'terra';

    public function getNumeroAleatorioDaSorte(){
        return 6;
    }
}

$pessoa = new Pessoa();

//exemplos validos:
echo "{$pessoa->getNumeroAleatorioDaSorte()} <br>";
echo "{$pessoa->nome} <br>";
echo "$pessoa->nome <br>";
 
//exemplos invalidos
echo "$pessoa->getNumeroAleatorioDaSorte()";
//notice: Undefined property Pessoa::$getNumeroAleatorioDaSorte
      
echo "Pessoa::$planeta";//notice: Undefined variable: planeta e imprime Planeta::
echo "{Pessoa::$planeta}";//notice: Undefined variable: planeta e imprime {Pessoa::}

echo "Pessoa::FOO";//imprime Pessoa::FOO
echo "{Pessoa::FOO}";//imprime {Pessoa::FOO}
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vkg6-hfsu)**

Answer (score 12):

A utilização de chaves com aspas duplas permite que sejam invocados métodos para gerar uma valor para ser concatenado na string.

É válido lembrar que vai funcionar somente com aspas duplas.

Neste seu exemplo você poderia tranquilamente remover as chaves ({}).

Answer (score 9):

> Para que servem as chavetas {} na seguinte string SQL usada em PHP
>   para MySQL?

Nesse caso para nada. O PHP vai interpretar as chaves e te retornar algo parecido com isso:

```
$tabela = 'user';
$fields = 'nome,email';
$placeholders = "'Jorge','jorge@gmail.com'";
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$placeholders})"

echo $sql; // INSERT INTO user (nome,email) VALUES ('Jorge','jorge@gmail.com')
```

Não aprofundando muito, pode ser mais interessante usar [*prepared statments*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php) e ter *queries* específicas por tabela ao invés de uma *string* genérica suscetível a [*SQL Injection*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php).

---

Quando o PHP encontra um `$` numa `string` entre aspas duplas `"` ou [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), ele tentará interpretar o valor da variável.

Por se tratar de uma string, podemos ter caracteres de se misturam com o nome das nossas variáveis ou queremos concatenar na `string` uma estrutura mais complexa, como a chamada de método de um objeto ou um `array` por exemplo.

É ai que entram as chaves (ou chavetas) `{}`. Próximas ao cifrão `$` eles atuam como um delimitador extra, possibilitando o uso de expressões simples ou complexas.

**Expressões Simples**

Quando desejamos exibir uma posição de `array` ou uma propriedade de um objeto por exemplo, ou até mesmo uma variável simples onde a continuação do texto influencia na variável que é chamada.

Exemplos:

```
<?php
$cerveja = 'Heineken';

// funciona, "'" é um caractere inválido para nome de variáveis
echo "O sabor das '$cerveja's é ótimo"; 

// não funciona, 's' é um caractere válido para nome de variáveis
// e o php procurará a variável $cervejas
echo "Ele bebeu algumas $cervejas";

echo "Ele bebeu algumas ${cerveja}s";   // funciona
echo "Ele bebeu algumas {$cerveja}s";   // funciona

$fruits = ['morango' => 'vermelho', 'banana' => 'amarelo'];

// Funciona
echo "A banana é {$fruits['banana']}.";

// Funciona, mas o PHP procura por uma constante chamada 'banana' antes,
// gerando um Notice no seu código.
echo "A banana é {$fruits[banana]}."

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->property = 'molezinha';

echo "Strings em php é {$obj->property}";
```

Algumas dessas expressões também funcionam se as chaves forem omitidas, como por exemplo `$obj->property`, porém o uso das chaves nos dá mais controle para exibir exatamente o que queremos.

**Expressões Complexas**

A sintaxe de chaves funcionam também com expressões complexas, como por exemplo vetores multi dimensionais, chamadas de métodos, funções ou [variáveis variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php).

Exemplos:

```
<?php

echo "Isto funciona: {$arr['foo'][3]}";
echo "Isto funciona também {$obj->values[3]->name}";    
echo "Este é o valor da variável chamada \$name: {${$name}}";    
echo "Este é o valor da variável usando o valor retornado da getName(): {${getName()}}";    
echo "Este é o valor da variável 
usando o valor retornado da \$object->getName(): {${$object>getName()}}";

$Bar = "a";
$Foo = "Bar";
$World = "Foo";
$Hello = "World";
$a = "Hello";

echo $a;           //Rertorna Hello
echo "$$a";        //Rertorna World
echo "${$$a}";     //Rertorna Foo     - Mais de um nível de variável variável
echo "${$$$a}";    //Rertorna Bar     - precisamos das chaves
echo "${$$$$a}";   //Rertorna a
```

---

Pessoalmente, sempre procuro incluir as chaves quando vou exibir diretamente estruturas complexas no PHP.

Quando utilizo variáveis simples, caso a `string` não colide com nomes de variáveis válidas, simplesmente omito as chaves `{}`.

Exemplos inspirados na [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Variáveis variáveis? Que quer isso dizer? Ou são variáveis (variam de valor) ou constantes (mantém o valor)

Comment: @JorgeB. o php permite que o conteúdo de uma variável invoque outra variável no seu código, criando assim uma variável que é variável, ou seja, que depende do valor de outra variável. Segue um [exemplo](http://ideone.com/DyuePY).

Comment: @gmsantos parabéns. Eu me enrolaria para explicar o que é variável variável