# Qual a diferença entre $var e $$var?

Tags: php

Qual a diferença entre uma variável $var e $$var no PHP? 
Como ela pode ser utilizada? 
Podem citar alguns exemplos de uso?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38427/para-que-servem-as-chavetas-numa-string-sql-em-php/38439#38439

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$var` é uma variável e `$$var` é uma "variável variável" cujo nome é o valor de $var.

veja o exemplo:

```
<?php

    $var = "hoje";
    echo $var;
    $$var = 'ontem';
    echo $hoje;
?>
```

Usar `$$var` não é muito comum (quase não vejo uso em aplicações) mas já vi uma vez: o criador do código tinha utilizado para criar variaveis dinamicamente com o nome da chave do array $_GET.

consulte:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Quais as vantagens de utilizar uma variável assim? Se é que existem...

Comment: @PauloCosta, editei com o uso.

Comment: @Paulo, a vantagem é quando necessita criar variáveis dinamicamente. O nome disso é "variável variável".
O mesmo esquema também pode ser usado para criar ou chamar funções, métodos e objetos, dependendo da versão do PHP.

Comment: @DanielOmine quais versões seriam estas?

Comment: Não se preocupe muito com a versão. Variáveis variáveis estão disponíveis desde antes da versão 5.
Os métodos variáveis (funções de classes) e instâncias variáveis (new class()), dependem de versões mais recentes. Mas se vc tem PHP 5.3 pelo menos, o que já é bem antigo, já estão disponíveis. Não sei dizer ao certo a versão correta, mas não tem muito com o que se preocupar. Consulte o manual para mais detalhes. Inseri os links na resposta do Ricardo.

Comment: Essa é mais uma gambiarra oferecida pelo PHP. Não use, meu amigo procurou uma variável no sistema durante uma semana e não achou. Quando foi ver o cara tinha usado essa tal de "variável variável"