# Criar variáveis programaticamente

Tags: php, variáveis

Existe a possibilidade de criar variáveis programaticamente?

Exemplo (**este exemplo não funciona, é somente para entender a ideia**):

Quero criar as variáveis: `$var0`,`$var1`,`$var2`,`$var3` e imprimir seu nome e valor.

```
$qtdVariaveis = 5;
$prefixo = 'var';
$valorPadrao = 10;

for ($c = 0; $c < 5; $c++) {

    echo $prefixo . $c = $valorPadrao;
}
```

Saída desejada:

```
$var0 = 10
$var1 = 10
$var2 = 10
$var3 = 10
```

Comment: Seria isso `${$prefixo . $c} = $valorPadrao;`?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr sim, só faltou imprimir o nome da variável. Existe essa função ?

Comment: É a mesma coisa.`echo ${$prefixo . $c}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Existe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60928/101) mas não deve fazer, não tem motivo para fazer isto.

Use um *array* e seja feliz. Seja com índice numérico sequencial, seja um associativo com o nome todo.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta ser duplicata, essa resposta é praticamente a única verdadeira. As raríssimas exceções só acontecem nas mãos de quem já entende muito bem da linguagem e do mecanismo, o que em PHP é mosca branca.