# PHP - Como inserir um link váriavel dentro de um a href variável?

Tags: php, html, variáveis, link

Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
  $link = "'index.php?id=echo ['post_id']; "
?>
```

```html
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<span class='survey-name'><a href='$link'>". $row['title'] ."</span>";
?>
```

Mas ao clicar no link ele apenas da um refresh na pagina, e nao direciona para a pagina do elemento variável em questão (), que é adicionado pelo DB mysql e exposto na home, mas ao clicar no link gostaria que direcionasse para a pagina de detalhes deste específico elemento que já está funcionando, apenas nao direcionando corretamente.

SQL:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `endereco` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `cidade` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `telefone` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

```html
function get_posts($id = null, $cat_id = null){
    $posts = array();
    $query = "SELECT `posts`.`id` AS `post_id` , `categories`.`id` AS `category_id`, `title`,`endereco`,`cidade`,`email`,`telefone`,`categories`.`name` FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`cat_id` " ;
    if(isset($id)){
        $id = (int)$id;
        $query .= " WHERE `posts`.`id` = {$id} ";
             }
    if(isset($cat_id)){
        $cat_id = (int)$cat_id;
        $query .= " WHERE `cat_id` = {$cat_id} ";
             }         
        
    $query .= "ORDER BY `post_id` DESC";
    
    $query = mysql_query($query);
    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $posts[] = $row;
   }
   return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que está faltando alguma coisa na definição do link, primeiro defina a variável corretamente, acredito que seja `$row` e não apenas `[post_id]` e por último imprima com echo o valor contido em `$link`.

```
<?php
   $posts = get_posts(); 

   $pagina = 'index.php?id=';
   $formato = "<span class='survey-name'><a href='%s%d'>%s</span>";

   foreach($post as $link){
      printf($formato, $pagina, $link['post_id'], $link['title']);
   }
```

### Relacionado

[Para que servem as chavetas {} numa string SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38427/91)

Comment: Ok, me direcionou para outra página, porém erro 404... Vou tentar explicar melhor: 
É um portal onde cadastro informações de lugares e gera-se uma id (post_id), e quero que quando clique no título de cada lugar (<span>), direcione para uma pagina com mais detalhes deste lugar, esta pagina esta pronta e retornando as informações corretamente, porém o direcionamento não.

Comment: Então o link foi gerado errado, pode mostrar da onde vem o `[post_id]`? o arquivo para redirecionar é o `index.php`? @PauloLima

Comment: Como posso te mostrar de maneira mais clara meu SQL? postando aqui ficou extremamente ruim de visualizar..
Obrigado @rray

Comment: Coloca o código php que pega o `post_id`, use o [link de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/74777/edit) na sua pergunta.

Comment: veja se dessa forma a pergunta ficou mais clara (desculpe a ignorância em algumas questões, sou begginer em PHP).

Comment: @PauloLima, sem problema a consulta que vc faz do php poderia adicionar ela na pergunta?

Comment: acredito que seja isto, correto?

Comment: Alterei a resposta veja se é isso @PauloLima.