# Verificar se um valor existe, senão imprimir outro

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<span class="end"><h1><?php echo $this->seo_tags->h1spam; ?></h1><h2><?php echo $this->seo_tags->spam; ?></h2></span>
<span class="end"><h3><?php echo $this->seo_tags->meta_description ?></h3><span><?php echo $this->seo_tags->meta_description; ?></span></span>
```

O que eu preciso fazer é: se o  `$this->seo_tags->spam` (no primeiro `span`) não existir, ele imprime apenas os valor do segundo `span`.

Tentei assim:

```
<?php if($this->seo_tags->spam != '') {
        echo '<span class="end"><h1><?php echo $this->seo_tags->h1spam; ?></h1><h2><?php echo $this->seo_tags->spam; ?></h2></span>';
      }else {
        echo '<span class="end"><h3><?php echo $this->seo_tags->meta_description ?></h3><span><?php echo $this->seo_tags->meta_description; ?></span></span>';
     }
?>
```

Porém ao invés dele imprimir os valores vindos do `$this->seo_tags->meta_description`, ele imprime apenas: `seo_tags->meta_description; ?>`. (Tanto no `h3`quanto no `span`).

O que estou fazendo de errado? Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que está errado no seu código é que você está tentando colocar um tag de PHP dentro de um `echo` que já é um comando de impressão do PHP.

```
<?php if(!$this->seo_tags->spam) {
        echo '<span class="end"><h1>' . $this->seo_tags->h1spam; . '</h1><h2>' . $this->seo_tags->spam . '</h2></span>';
      }else {
        echo '<span class="end"><h3>' . $this->seo_tags->meta_description . '</h3><span>' . $this->seo_tags->meta_description . '</span></span>';
     }
?>
```

Quando você já está escrevendo um código em PHP que está contido dentro da tag `<?php` você escrever em uma string novamente esta mesma tag, não será interpretada como linguagem dinâmica (há menos que você use `eval` mas isso é perigoso e desnecessário para seu problema).

Então você pode usar `.` para concatenar uma *string* em PHP, assim como demonstrei no código exemplo da sua correção.

#### Condicional fracamente tipada em PHP:

Quanto a expressão na sua condicional, PHP é uma linguagem fracamente tipada o que lhe permite fazer comparações entre tipos distintos de variáveis.

Para verificar se uma variável está vazia você pode nega-la `!$variavel` isso é, `''` ou `false` ou `null` ou `0` todos irão retornar *verdadeiros* nesta expressão. Também pode usar `empty($variavel)` caso seja uma string ou array vazia isto irá retornar *verdadeiro*.

### Forma alternativa:

Para resolver o mesmo caso de forma alternativa, você também pode usar o PHP para parar de interpretar seu código entre os comandos, isso mostraria seu HTML em alguns editores WYSIWYG caso esteja usando um.

```
<?php if(!$this->seo_tags->spam) { ?>
        <span class="end"><h1><?php $this->seo_tags->h1spam; ?></h1><h2><?php $this->seo_tags->spam; ?></h2></span>
<?php } else { ?>
        <span class="end"><h3><?php $this->seo_tags->meta_description; ?></h3><span><?php $this->seo_tags->meta_description; ?></span></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Este código resulta na mesma coisa que o anterior, mas em vez do HTML estar dentro de um `echo` do PHP, você interrompe o processador do PHP entre os blocos de condicional.

#### Curiosidade sobre short-tag em PHP

Quando usando código entre blocos como no exemplo anterior existe a possibilidade de usar short-tags (ela deve estar ativa no seu PHP.INI, utilize o `phpinfo()` para saber se ela está ativa), consiste em usar apenas `<?=$variavel?>` repare que desta maneira fica mais curta a escrita:

```
<?php if(!$this->seo_tags->spam) { ?>
        <span class="end"><h1><?= $this->seo_tags->h1spam ?></h1><h2><?= $this->seo_tags->spam ?></h2></span>
<?php } else { ?>
        <span class="end"><h3><?= $this->seo_tags->meta_description ?></h3><span><?= $this->seo_tags->meta_description ?></span></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Aspas simples e dupla são diferentes

No PHP aspas simples e duplas são diferentes, caso queira entender melhor como elas funcionam, olhe esta questão: [Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php)

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou! E valeu pela explicação, me tirou várias dúvidas, sou iniciante e ainda tenho esses erros "idiotas". :p hehe

Comment: @GWER é um prazer ajudar, também fui iniciante um dia amigo, mas é trazendo as dúvidas a tona que aprendemos.

Answer (score 3):

Eu nem sou programador `PHP`, mas acho que você deveria fazer assim (concatenando o HTML com os valores dinâmicos do `PHP`):

```
<?php if($this->seo_tags->spam != '') {
        echo '<span class="end"><h1>'.$this->seo_tags->h1spam.'</h1><h2>'.$this->seo_tags->spam.'</h2></span>';
      }else {
        echo '<span class="end"><h3>'.$this->seo_tags->meta_description .'</h3><span>'.$this->seo_tags->meta_description.'</span></span>';
     }
?>
```