# Dúvida sobre SQL em PHP

Tags: php, sql

Eu neste momento estou a realizar um trabalho que é preciso aceder a base de dados, e tive muita dificuldade em algumas *queries*, entre elas a *query* do `UPDATE`. Mas depois de muito procurar achei uma solução e queria perguntar qual é a diferença, qual a que é melhor, etc.

Eu usei

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela SET campo1 = ' ".$1." ', campo2 = ' ".$2." ' WHERE user = ' " .$3. " ');
```

Mas o que funcionou foi :

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela SET campo1 = '$1', campo2 = '$2' WHERE user=$3");
```

Ou seja retirei pontos finais, aspas etc.. Faz alguma diferença? Eu usei com os pontos e as aspas em *queries* do tipo `SELECT` e `INSERT` e funcionou.

Comment: Sua variável chama `$1`? nenhuma forma é legal pq usa funções obsoletas e removidas das versões mais novas do PHP(7)

Comment: Não. Apenas estava a tentar criar um exemplo haha

Comment: Eu sempre pensei que o ponto era para diferenciar o php da query. as aspas penso que são por causa de ser uma query, porque no Phpmyadmin também é preciso.

Comment: Essa pergunta tá fazendo uma confusão danada entre query e operação de _string_ em PHP. Sugiro aprender separadamente cada coisa.

Comment: Então, o ponto serve para concatenar(juntar) strings(textos), no php resumidamente a diferença entre as aspas simples e as duplas é, o primeiro tipo não lê o valor de uma variáve dentro já a segunda sim. Exemplo: `$v = 'valor'; echo '$valor<br>'; echo "$valor";` Para mais detalhes veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4652/91). No SQL as diferença entre elas é que geralmente as simples delimitam valores e as duplas podem ser o caracter de escape em nomes de colunas com palavras chaves/reservadas. Se tiver alguma dúvida coloca ai no comentário.

Comment: o erro que esta tendo é que tem um espaço entre as aspas simples e as duplas, troque `' ".$1." '` por `'".$1."'` e nos outros tbm

Answer (score 1):

Em PHP, o operador . (ponto) concatena strings, e em strings podem ser delimitadas com aspas duplas ou simples. Em MySQL, strings são sempre delimitadas por aspas simples. Nos trechos apresentados, a string de PHP é com aspas duplas.

O primeiro trecho não deve ter funcionado porque, sem querer, acrescentava espaço em branco antes e depois do valor da variável inserida. Ilustrando com código:

`$nome = "João da Silva";`

`"' " . $nome . " '"` resulta em `' João da Silva '`.

`"'$nome'"` resulta em `'João da Silva'`.

O segundo trecho funciona como se deve. Recomendo trocar `$1`, `$2`, etc., por nomes representativos das colunas da tabela.