# Usar aspas simples ou duplas para strings em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma diferença entre escrever uma string literal entre aspas simples ou duplas?

Exemplo:

```
var s = 'texto';
// ou
var s = "texto";
```

Comment: Melhor prática baseado em quê?

Comment: Relacionada (SOen): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @MarcellAlves eu dei um "tapinha" na sua pergunta. Se você não gostar, pode reverter a edição, aí eu vou deixar o meu downvote por citar "melhor prática" sem contexto nenhum. Obs. sobre a edição: Tirei o segundo exemplo pq string é sempre string, não faz diferença onde for usado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É uma questão de gosto. Elas não fazem diferença em JavaScript.

Pode haver casos em que uma é mais prática, por exemplo:

```js
var stringA = 'Olá Mc\'Neil';
var stringB = "Olá Mc'Neil";

console.log(stringA, '|', stringB); // Olá Mc'Neil | Olá Mc'Neil
```

Em outras linguagens [como o PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4652/129) é diferente.

Comment: mas tem a questão de consumo?

Comment: @MagicHat explica melhor o que queres dizer com "consumo"? referes-te ao que juntei depois no exemplo?

Comment: por exemplo nessa resposta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php#4680) é afirmado que em php há um consumo diferente de memória, não testei para saber se é real, entretanto se for isso ocorre tmb em js ?

Comment: Essa era uma das minhas dúvidas.

Comment: @MagicHat que eu saiba os compiladores não fazem tratamento diferente. Dando uma olhada a posts que falam sobre este assunto  ([este](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/javascript-quotes.html), [este](http://stackoverflow.com/q/242813/2256325), ou lendo [diretivas da ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14.1))  ambas são tratadas como iguais.

Comment: Para mim o que dizes é uma referência em js, então ok ...

Comment: @MagicHat :) É sempre bom questionar. Eu não sei tudo.

Comment: ah sim, mas em js parece que se tá quase lá heuheuehu