# Problema com url em php

Tags: php, url

Estou com um problema com minha url, quando vou para a paginá **projeto-detalhado.php** ela mostra na url o id do projeto que está sendo detalhado, assim:

> http://localhost/opentag/projeto-detalhado.php?id=14

Quando vou para a pagina **altera-projeto.php** se tudo der certo, vou para o **projeto-detalhado.php** passando a id do projeto que alterei:

```
header("Location: projeto-detalhado.php?id='$projeto->getId()'");
```

O Problema é  que as urls se misturam e vira uma bagunça e a pagina **projeto-detalhado** não consegue buscar o projeto.

> http://localhost/opentag/projeto-detalhado.php?id=%27()%27

OBS.: estou pegando o id do projeto via get para fazer a busca e listar os detalhes dele.

```
$projeto = $projetoDAO->buscaProjetoPorId($_GET['id']);
```

Existe alguma função para que eu limpe a url, e ela só tenha oque eu mandei no header() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando aspas simples no local errado, [veja informações aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php), exatamente aqui:

```
header("Location: projeto-detalhado.php?id='$projeto->getId()'");
```

Está inserindo dois `'` ao link, ele possui o código `%27`, [como pode ver aqui](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) e [aqui](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), portanto o link automaticamente será, *pelo navegador*:

```
/projeto-detalhado.php?id=%27[ALGUMA-COISA]%27
```

---

Para corrigir os `%27` remova os `'`, você pode:

```
header("Location: projeto-detalhado.php?id={$projeto->getId()}");
```

Se preferir pode usar:

```
header('Location: projeto-detalhado.php?id='.$projeto->getId());
```

Comment: Opa ! vlw funcionou