# Problemas ao definir string de url cujo parâmetro query string contenha o caractere cifrão ($)

Tags: php, json, url

Estou usando uma API WS em JSON

que a URL é

```
https://api.movidesk.com/public/v1/persons?token=52ee6ca5-8639-422b-bafe-470013c11176&$filter=profileType eq 2
```

que é o exemplo em que a documentação da API passa.
quando jogo no navegador fica

```
https://api.movidesk.com/public/v1/persons?token=52ee6ca5-8639-422b-bafe-470013c11176&$filter=profileType%20eq%202
```

Mas as informações aparecem

Meu problema é quando vou usar a API em PHP

Exemplo

```
 <?php $json = file_get_contents("https://api.movidesk.com/public/v1/persons?token=52ee6ca5-8639-422b-bafe-470013c11176&$filter=profileType%20eq%202");
      $cliente = json_decode($json);
```

me retorna o seguinte erro

> Notice: Undefined variable: filter in C:\xampp\htdocs\Maps\json.php on line 54
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.movidesk.com/public/v1/persons?token=52ee6ca5-8639-422b-bafe-470013c11176&$filter=profileType%20eq%202): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\Maps\json.php on line 54

Comment: Tente remover o cifrão de `&$filter` ou escaplo `&\$filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o parâmetro da url tem um valor chamado `$filter`.

No trecho em que você tenta fazer a requisição com `file_get_contents`, você está usando aspas duplas. Quando você faz isso, o PHP interpreta valores que começam com `$` como sendo o valor da variável.

Isso aconteceu porque você está usando aspas duplas. Apenas use aspas simples que resolverá o problema.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.movidesk.com/public/v1/persons?token=52ee6ca5-8639-422b-bafe-470013c11176&$filter=profileType%20eq%202');

$cliente = json_decode($json);
```

Para mais informações, leia:

[Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php)

Comment: Wallace deu certinho, Muito Obrigado! nem e atendei a isso

Comment: @JeanPrado ok. Eu percebo que você é novo na comunidade. Se a pergunta solucionou o problema, considere votar/marcar como útil a mesma :p

Comment: @JeanPrado [...] Usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Comment: Eu não adicionei na resposta, mas é por essas e outras que prefiro usar `sprintf` para deixar as string com "slots" para depois definir os valores.