# Quebra de Linha

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boa noite, faço uma consulta e na minha consulta não consigo fazer quebra de linha, os resultados aparecem um do lado do outro, já tem `\n`, `\\n`, `<br />`,`<BR>` no PHP e não funcionou... Alguém pode me Ajudar ?

**JavaScript**

```
function autocomplet() {

    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#cfuncionario').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/cfuncionario.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                var availableTags = [data];
            alert(availableTags);
            $("#cfuncionario").autocomplete({
                 source: availableTags

             });

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$keyword = $_POST['keyword'].'%';
$query = "SELECT nome_funcionario FROM funcionarios WHERE nome_funcionario LIKE '$keyword' LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

if($result)
 {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['nome_funcionario'].'\n';



  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Se você quiser quebra de linha no html, use <br>, \n serve para pular linha na janelinha de alert do javascript.

Comment: ele não quebra a linha tbm, ele fica mateus<br>mateus soares<br> ...

Comment: Já tentou retornar JSON pelo PHP e tratá-lo no JavaScript?

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: Utilizando [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) no PHP e [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) no JavaScript. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consideremos que seu código PHP gere o seguinte resultado:

```html
Kevin T. Sullivan<br />
Nicolash Correia Cunha<br />
Lavinia Azevedo Lima<br />
Isabelle Lima Silva<br />
Kauan Silva Almeida<br />
Victor Costa Carvalho<br />
Sophia Pinto Barbosa<br />
Vitor Goncalves Barros<br />
Daniel Sousa Melo<br />
Davi Gomes Correia<br />
```

> **Nota**: os nomes acima foram gerados aleatoriamente através do sistema *Fake Name Generator* e qualquer semelhança com a realidade será mera coincidência.

Podemos tentar resgatar estes valores com JavaScript utilizando uma requisição assíncrona da seguinte forma:

```js
$(() => {
  $("#name").on("keyup", function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/acwoss/25f02a59086ecc1d11fd2201586420db/raw/1d372b624d4cc2416685c0c438eff75c0912747c/SOpt-200357-response.html",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#name").autocomplete({source: [data]});
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
```

> **Nota**: o código da requisição foi minimamente alterado para funcionar conforme o contexto do exemplo, porém, manteve-se a ideia original da pergunta.

Veja que o resultado é exatamente o código HTML gerado pelo PHP, mas é uma *raw string*, isto é, o JavaScript não saberá como tratá-la. Para que ele possa interpretar o resultado, você deve indicar como isso deve ser feito; e a maneira mais fácil é utilizar formatos conhecidos, como o JSON.

```js
$(() => {
  $("#name").on("keyup", function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/acwoss/bba40268dd678cb4ee3b2291cdede7e2/raw/8586099a9451f44d3ef86046023bbe8c8f9ba202/SOpt-200357-response.json",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#name").autocomplete({source: data});
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
```

Indicando que o retorno será do formato JSON, com `dataType: 'json'`, e o PHP gerando, de fato, uma resposta neste formato, o resultado obtido no JavaScript já será uma lista de valores que poderá ser passada ao plugin de autocomplemento.

Eu não tenho condições de criar aqui um exemplo que se aproxime ao da sua pergunta, mas acredito que se não for exatamente o código abaixo, será algo muito próximo.

**PHP gerando JSON**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$keyword = $_POST['keyword'].'%';
$query = "SELECT nome_funcionario FROM funcionarios WHERE nome_funcionario LIKE '$keyword' LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if($result)
{
  $output = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $output[] = $row['nome_funcionario'];
  }

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

**JavaScript recebendo JSON**

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 1;
    var keyword = $('#cfuncionario').val();

    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/cfuncionario.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword: keyword},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#cfuncionario").autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o problema seja você usar `'\n'` ao invés de `"\n"` com aspas duplas.

Existe uma pequena diferença entre ambas.

Outra solução é concatenar com a constante `PHP_EOL`.

```
echo $row['nome_funcionario'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Leia:

[Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php)