# Por que usar diferentes aspas me da diferentes resultados?

Tags: php

Por que eu usando assim, sai diferente? Não é a mesma coisa?

```
$teste = 'HAHAHA';

echo "Variavel $teste<br>"; // Retorna Variavel HAHAHA
echo 'Variavel $teste'; // Retorna Variavel $teste
```

Comment: Nessa pergunta você encontrará a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php