# Pegando dados de formularios em php com ciclos

Tags: php, jquery, html

Preciso usar algum ciclo de PHP para obter os dados do formulário em uma pagina de processamento. Pensei em colocar uma variável de contagem dentro de uma caixa de identificação de nome do input, assim:

```
$c=1;
while($c <= 5) {
  $tabela[$c]= $_POST['nome$c'];
}
```

Poderia imprimir depois usando:

```
$c2= 1;
while($c2 <= 5) {
  echo $tabela[$c2];
}
```

O servidor não consegue identificar o `$_POST['nome$c'];`, não sei o que faço

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre [devido a diferença de aspas simples e duplas no php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php), recomendo que leia isto para entender. No seu caso você tem duas opções (na verdade tem outras opções):

Use `'...'.$c`:

```
$_POST['nome'.$c];
```

Use `"...$c"`:

```
$_POST["nome$c"];
```

Escolha uma delas.

Comment: vou testar, obrigado pela ajuda!