# Phpmailer envia e-mail mas não envia valores das variáveis

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Estou fazendo um sistema para enviar e-mails com os dados do formulário de contato para o administrador. Até aí tudo bem, consegui configurar tudo, envia o e-mail, mas há um problema bem peculiar. Os dados da mensagem e assunto não são enviados para o e-mail. Ele simplesmente vai com o nome da variável, sem o valor dela. Como resolver? Segue os códigos do formulário e do php:

**contato.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1423" />
    <title>Contato | Lizard Fishing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/estilo.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="author" content="Samuel Santos, Thiago Lamonica e Ruan Vicente Bianco" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />
    <meta name="rating" content="general" />
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header header_geral">
        <?php
            include "header.html";
        ?>
    </header>
    <main class="main main_geral main_contato">
        <h2 class="title_content">Contato</h2>
        <h3 class="subtitle_content subtitle_contato">Entre em contato conosco!</h3>
        <br />
            <div class="form_contato">
                <form name="form_contato" method="post" action="enviar_contato.php">
                    <p>
                        <label>Nome:</label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="nome_contato" class="text_input" size="38" required />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>E-mail:</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="email" name="email_contato" class="text_input" size="38" required />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Assunto</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" name="assunto_contato" class="text_input" size="38" required />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Mensagem:</label>
                        <br/>
                        <textarea name="mensagem_contato" rows="10" cols="40" class="text_input" required ></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="button_submit" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="dados_contato">
                <p class="text_content text_contato">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Lizard-Fishing-Equipamentos-Para-Pesca-361157610633775" class="link_fb" target="_blank"><img src="icon/fb.png" width="25" class="icon_fb" />&nbsp;<b>Lizard Fishing</b></a>
                    <br/>
                    <b>Televendas:</b> (55)11 2534-7082
                    <br/>
                    <b>Celular:</b> (55)11 96437-8004
                    <br/>
                    <b>E-mail:</b> contato@lizardfishing.com.br                    
                </p>
            </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**enviar_contato.php**

```
<?php
    $nome=$_POST["nome_contato"];
    $email=$_POST["email_contato"];
    $assunto=$_POST["assunto_contato"];
    $mensagem=$_POST["mensagem_contato"];

include 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "meuemail@hotmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*********";
$mail->setFrom('meuemail@hotmail.com', 'Administrador');
$mail->addAddress('$email_contato', '$nome_contato');
$mail->addReplyTo('$nome_contato', '$nome_contato');
$mail->addCC('meuemail@hotmail.com', 'Administrador');

$mail->isHTML(true);  

$mail->Subject = '$assunto_contato';
$mail->Body = '$mensagem_contato';

if (!$mail->send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message sent!";
}


?>
```

Comment: Onde você utiliza as variáveis, troque as aspas simples (`'`) por aspas duplas (`"`). O PHP só analisa variáveis presentes em *string* definidas com aspas duplas. Você pode também deixar sem as aspas se o valor for apenas a da variável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação do PHP define que aspas simples são literais simples, não processadas. Já as aspas duplas serão processadas [ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php).

Portanto faça o que o Anderson Carlos Woss indicou no comentário "Onde você utiliza as variáveis, troque as aspas simples (') por aspas duplas ("). O PHP só analisa variáveis presentes em string definidas com aspas duplas. Você pode também deixar sem as aspas se o valor for apenas a da variável."

```
$mail->Subject = "$assunto_contato";
$mail->Body = "$mensagem_contato";
```

Comment: deu tudo certo, Leo Caracciolo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Forte abraço!

Comment: @SamuelSantos já que deu tudo certo,  leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Na linha `$mail->Body = '$mensagem_contato';` você deve informar um código HTML com as variáveis. Por exemplo:

```
$html = 'Nome: ' . $nome .'<br>';
$html .= 'E-mail: ' . $email .'<br>';
$html .= 'Assunto: ' . $assunto .'<br>';
$html .= 'Mensagem: ' . $mensagem .'<br>';

$mail->Body = $html;
```

Comment: Fiz tudo que recomendou e rodou perfeito! Muito obrigado, amigo. Sucesso!