# Enviar valor para função javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Olá

Eu estou tentando enviar um valor para função ao clicar no botão, oque pode estar errado ?

```html
echo"<button id=".$nome." onclick='produtoComprado(/'".$detalhes."/')'>".$nome."</button>";
```

Obrigado

Comment: `$detalhes` é o quê? _Number_, _String_, _Object_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa aspas duplas `"`, não existe a necessidade de fazer a concatenação dessa forma, você pode apenas colocar a variável, e se precisar colocar aspas dentro do texto, é só usar a barra invertida antes `\"` para escapar, o código fica mais limpo e facilita a vida.

```
echo "<button id=\"$nome\" onclick=\"produtoComprado('$detalhes')\">$nome</button>";
```

Segue o exemplo rodando: [https://repl.it/MMxC/5](https://repl.it/MMxC/4)

Para aprender mais sobre a diferença das aspas: [Diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php)

Answer (score 1):

Estava faltando duas aspas simples ao definir o id do botão, teste:

```
echo "<button id='".$nome."' onclick='produtoComprado(/'".$detalhes."/')'>".$nome."</button>";
```