# Aplicar classe a um link dentro de um echo?

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho esse echo abaixo e gostaria de aplicar a classe `buttonlink` nele, porém eu não estou conseguindo.

Não sei se são as aspas, essa barra invertida ou se não é possível fazer isso mesmo, se alguém puder ajudar.

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . " class="buttonlink"\">".$resultado["dataup"]." / " . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
```

Comment: É porque faltou o **`$`**

Comment: Ah, pera. Você quer que "buttonlink" seja **literal**?

Comment: @LINQ Como assim literal?

Comment: Literal, cara. [Literal](https://www.dicio.com.br/literal/).

Comment: @LINQ Eu quero mudar a cor e o tamanho da letra que sai ao carregar a página, entendeu? Aplicando a classe `buttonlink`

Comment: Arthur, percebi que você tentou marcar várias respostas como corretas. Isso só pode ser feito em uma resposta, ok?

Comment: @LINQ Eu achei que dava, mas marquei a sua por ter sido o primeiro a responder!

Comment: Só pra constar, o downvote não é meu, mesmo assim votei pra fechar porque isso é o básico do PHP e já foi bastante debatido aqui, acho que a melhor pergunta para entender isto é esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4652/3635 que fala da característica da linguagem. **Observação:** as respostas estão todas corretas, mas quero deixar bem claro apesar de não haver diferenças significativas do uso de aspas-simples no HTML, a questão é mais que você pode se confundir se misturar diferentes uso, mas é só uma dica, nada grave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É preciso escapar as aspas.

Inclusive, está quase certo no código original, mas sobrou uma aspa dupla e faltou o escape na primeira aspa dupla.

Pra corrigir pode fazer só isso:

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . " class=\"buttonlink\">".$resultado["dataup"]." / " . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
```

Ou, organizar melhor seu código e deixar assim:

```
$link = $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"];
$descr = $resultado["dataup"]." / " . $resultado["nomearq"];

echo "<a href='{$link}' class='buttonLink'>{$descr}</a><br>";
```

Também é possível fazer uma manobra usando aspas simples e duplas, mas nem vou deixar exemplo disso porque fica um código horrível.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, vlw demais, ajudou muito!!

Answer (score 3):

Sim, o problema é as aspas no meio da sua *string*. Eu particularmente recomendaria você a utilizar a [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php) neste caso.

```
<?php

$href = $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"];
$label = $resultado["dataup"]." / " . $resultado["nomearq"];

printf("<a href='%s' class='buttonLink'>%s</a><br>", $href, $label);
```

O código fica muito mais legível. Ou até mesmo:

```
<?php

$href = $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"];
$label = $resultado["dataup"]." / " . $resultado["nomearq"];

echo "<a href='{$href}' class='buttonLink'>{$label}</a><br>";
```

Comment: PHP tem interpolação de string quase que implícita e você usando `printf`. Ah não =D

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson, ajudou demais, deu certo aqui!!

Answer (score 3):

Tente usar aspas simples, fica mais fácil.

```
echo "<a href=" . $pasta . $resultado['nomearq'] . " class='buttonlink'>".$resultado['dataup']." / " . $resultado['nomearq'] . "</a><br />";
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, sempre me perco nessas aspas simples e duplas kkk tenho que acostumar ainda!

Answer (score 0):

Segue:

O resultado é o mesmo em ambos, porém se usar 'echo' ele tentar 'printar' como elemento e só aparece a palavra com o link.

**Usando var_dump:**

```
var_dump('<a href="'.$resultado["nomearq"].'" class="buttonlink">'.$resultado["nomearq"].'</a><br>');
```

**Usando echo:**

```
echo '<a href="'.$resultado["nomearq"].'" class="buttonlink">'.$resultado["nomearq"].'</a><br>';
```