# Erro ao gravar data convertida no banco phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando gravar um formulário no banco de dados, nesse formulário tem um campo para data que contém máscara `dd/mm/aaaa`. Para gravar no banco eu preciso converter essa data para `aaaa-mm-dd`, até ai eu consegui `str_replace`, o problema é que quando eu vou gravar essa váriavel no banco ele me retorno um erro e não grava nada no banco. Segue me código:

```
<form action="envia.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class=""><b>Sistema</b></label>
                    <select name="sistema" class="form-control" required/>
                        <option selected>Escolha o sistema</option>
                        <option value="ATPH">ATPH </option>
                        <option value="DPPH">DPPH Pagamento</option>
                        <option value="EFPH">EFPH </option>
                        <option value="SCPH">SCPH</option>
                        <option value="GEPH">GEPH</option>
                        <option value="BICLI">BIPH</option>
                        <option value="BISER">BIPH</option>
                    </select>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class=""><b>Data</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="data" class="form-control" maxlength="10" onkeypress="mascaraData(this)" placeholder="Digite a data da Revisão" required/>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">   
                <label class=""><b>Versão</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="versao" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a Versão" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class=""><b>Revisão</b></label>
                <input type="text" name="revisao" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a Revisão" required/>    
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class=""><b>Arquivo</b></label>
                <input type="file" name="arquivo" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                <div class="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary upload">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image: SQL]

[image: Estrutura do banco]

Comment: Já tentou fazer um var_dump da variável $query, só pra ter certeza que durante a aplicação ela está recebendo os parâmetros de forma correta? Aliás, agora reparei uma coisa, a formatação vc usa no echo e não na variável. Ou seja sua variável apenas está gravada 07-11-2018 por exemplo.

Comment: Cara, então o que eu tentei foi fazer o cara abaixo respondeu, e coloquei um echo para ler a `($data)`, conforme o print (http://prntscr.com/lfhn8i) ele lê a data no formato correto, mas cai no mesmo else lá em baixo e não grava. Sou meio iniciante em sql, como eu posso usar esse var_dump ?

Comment: O var_dump seria no php mesmo, abaixo da sua query faça assim: `var_dump($query);`  Ai comenta a linha do resultado e do if. Ai faz só a impressão desse var_dump na tela para ver como está recebendo a query

Comment: (http://prntscr.com/lfhvgn). Seria isso ? Não imprime nada na tela.

Comment: ATUALIZANDO: Achei um array na internet que converte essa data, conf rme print : ( http://prntscr.com/lfiqyc ). Feito essa alteração, tentei enviar para o banco, ele me retorna essa mensagem ( http://prntscr.com/lfiqgw ) que é `o echo ($query);`, e não grava nada no banco e retorna o mesmo else de antes. Ainda não achei uma solução.

Comment: Desculpa a demora meu caro, fiquei na rua a tarde toda. Interessante, aparentemente sua variável está recebendo corretamente. Os 2 primeiros valores "versao" e "revisao" estão gravando normalmente no banco de dados?

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui, acho que é o formato de string que ta atrapalhando, coloca tudo entre parenteses deixe sua query assim: `$query = "INSERT INTO $table (versao, revisao, data) VALUES ('$versao', '$revisao', '$data')";`

Comment: Consegui, com a resposta do cara ali em baixo, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seu problema seja com apenas a forma como você inseriu as variáveis na string que será enviada para o banco. Tente assim:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (versao, revisao, data) VALUES ('".$versao."', '".$revisao."', '".$data."')";
```

É feio, é chato de escrever, mas acho que resolve o problema. Os valores devem estar dentro de 'aspas' mas como vem de uma variável precisa estar fora de uma string, então vc fecha a string e concatena os valores, um por um.

Comment: Cara, deu certinho, o jeito que o insert estava escrito estava errado ? Ou existe várias formas ?

Comment: Eu conheço duas formas, essa que você usou que lista primeiro as colunas e depois os valores que vão nelas. A outra seria assim:

$query = "INSERT INTO tabela SET coluna='valor', coluna2='valor2'";

Porém a questão não é essa, sua query estava correta. O problema é o uso de aspas simples ' e aspas ". Este post contém informações sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php

Resumindo, eu sempre faço concatenação, da forma como eu fiz no exemplo da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver imprimindo corretamente o valor da data, faça a variável receber esse valor. Veja:

```
$data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));
```

Claro que depois de vc ter usado o str_replace

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lfh0lg Tentei fazer o que você disse e depois tentei imprimir pra ver se deu certo e continua não gravando e caindo no `else`. (http://prntscr.com/lfh250) imprimiu isso que ta no print, a data que veio do form era 06/12/2018, então ele converteu certo só não salva no banco.