# Enviar e-mail com PHPMailer utilizando variável PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

estou tentando enviar e-mail com a classe PHPMailer mas estou tendo problema.

Aqui eu consigo numa boa:

```
$mail->AddAddress('destinatario@email.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');
```

Mas quando coloco uma variável, não vai... retorna o seguinte erro: "You must provide at least one recipient email address."

```
$mail->AddAddress('$email', '$nome');
```

Como posso resolver esse probleminha? Agradeço!

EDIT: RESOLVIDO.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
' . $email . '
```

Comment: Tenta descobrir por que os dados dessa variável não chega ai, coloca o seu código pra nós entendermos

Comment: Você não resolveu, porque não entende como funciona aspas simples e aspas composta, precisa fazer leitura a respeito e se a variavel `$email` e `$nome` for um texto não precisa de aspas ... afinal são textos.

Comment: Pode ser considerado duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php

Answer (score 0):

Tenta deixar assim, o php ja trata essas duas variáveis como strings, então não precisa se preocupar com as aspas(" "), tente dessa maneira, apenas não encontrava o email "$email", ja que você colocou entre aspas.

```
$mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);
```

Comment: Tente explicar o motivo do erro do amigo ...

Comment: Pronto meu caro... Editado, espero que lhe ajude.

Comment: Leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php ai ta a resposta ... não sei se encaixa na pergunta como duplicata mas, o motivo de conceito é esse, mas, também tem outro problema da não necessidade de aspas

Comment: Creio que não é duplicata, mas seu comentário agrega bastante para solução