# Enviar uma variável pela url do IFrame

Tags: php, asp, iframe

Estou começando a programar em PHP e tenho uma página em PHP e quero um enviar uma variável para uma página ASP.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo enviar a variável `$codselecionado`, se eu colocar o valor na mão, fica certinho, a página ASP identifica esse valor e da andamento no projeto

```
echo '<iframe name="atualizaguia1" allowfullscreen=true frameborder=0 src="atualizaguia1.asp?codtitulo=52022"  target="_self" scrolling=auto>';
```

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado nesse envio

```
echo '<iframe name="atualizaguia1" allowfullscreen=true frameborder=0 src="atualizaguia1.asp?codtitulo=$codselecionado"  target="_self" scrolling=auto>';
```

A variável `$codselecionado` está preenchida corretamente com o valor, já fiz diversos testes nela.

Comment: Amigo, poste o código que você desenvolveu até o momento para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando aspas simples para delimitar o retorno do `echo`. Ao usar aspas simples, a variável `$codselecionado` dentro não é processada ([veja este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4652/8063)), ou seja, ela será enviada de forma literal: o ASP receberá o valor "$codselecionado" e não o valor que a variável representa no PHP.

O que você pode fazer é delimitar o `echo` com aspas duplas, porque dentro das aspas duplas a variável é processada, só que será preciso trocar as aspas duplas dos atributos do iframe para aspas simples:

```
echo "<iframe name='atualizaguia1' allowfullscreen=true frameborder=0
src='atualizaguia1.asp?codtitulo=$codselecionado'  target='_self' scrolling=auto>";
```

Ou então manter como está e concatenar a variável:

```
echo '<iframe name="atualizaguia1" allowfullscreen=true frameborder=0
src="atualizaguia1.asp?codtitulo='. $codselecionado. '"  target="_self" scrolling=auto>';
```

Comment: Sam agradeço a ajuda, realmente as duas formas funcionaram perfeitamente