# Strings: é pertinente usar 'aspas' simples para ganho de performance no PHP ou isso é insignificante?

Tags: php, string, desempenho, concatenação-de-string

Sei que isso era até listado como boas práticas no passado, mas com o PHP nas suas últimas versões (7 e 8) que são mais rápidas ainda faz algum sentido essa "boa prática" na hora de concatenar strings?

A pergunta não é sobre a diferença entre aspas simples e dupla, é sobre questão de performance do uso das aspas simples em comparação a aspas duplas.

Comment: Relacionado ao passado, com teste de desempenho: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php#answer-417874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo no PHP 5.x não havia praticamente diferença, então não tem muito o que debater sobre algo que mudou no PHP7.x ou 8.x.

Só serão "lentas" (e provavelmente será algo mínimo que não teria significado relevante) se que executasse um número irreal de operações por segundo, talvez se fosse um loop rodando milhões de strings por segundo e que provavelmente fossem escritos manualmente para serem muito grandes, mas um cenário assim é bastante improvável, e mesmo que ocorra de precisar escrever algo assim, então provavelmente o problema com o seu código não serão as aspas, mas como ele está sendo escrito no geral. De qualquer forma se estiver curioso você mesmo pode fazer um teste e notar que muda e tem ganho de performance.

Agora escrever variáveis simples, strings simples, "embarcar HTML", etc, em situações normais aspas duplas e simples **terão praticamente a mesma performance**.

Talvez seja importante ressaltar que muitos mitos se formaram em volta de linguagens e APIs, um exemplo são histórias como exemplo de pessoas que afirmavam para não usar require ou include, o que **talvez** fosse um pouco diferente [apenas quando se tratando de require_once e include_once](https://seeit.org/2010/06/11/php-the-include-include_once-performance-debate/), mas é tão infima a diferença, que usar os construtores `_once` quando pertinente não seria nenhuma desvantagem.

O objetivo de usar aspas simples não é sobre performance, é sobre no que ela se difere das *aspas duplas* e do *heredoc*, fora evitar que algo como `$foobar` se torne uma "concatenação" para string atual, as aspas simples também são usadas quando você não deseja que *sequências de escape para caracteres especiais expandidos*.

Resumindo, a questão não é exatamente performance, isso só vai afetar em um cenário muito especifico (e provavelmente exagerado sem motivo). O que de fato mata a performance são esses frameworks web que tentam reinventar a roda, aonde o PHP já faz as coisas naturalmente, eles querem reinventar o PHP, nesses cenários de frameworks, a maioria que testei em uma requisição simples consome pelo menos 4MB de memória, enquanto escrever algo em PHP *puro*, consome uma média de 600kB de memória, um *hello world* simples na maioria dos frameworks costuma responder entre 10 a 50 pessoas por segundo (valor aproximado), escrever um *hello world* em PHP *puro*, costuma responder de 800 a 1000 pessoas por segundo

> só pra constar, eu fiz benchmark desses valores todos, com 5 frameworks diferentes e PHP normal, para quem me conhece sabe que é algo que sempre bato na tecla, benchmark. Como os testes foram feitos para ilustrar uma documentação minha não tenho como trazer eles para cá, mas logo separo testes em `PHP 7.3+` (isso inclui o 8.x) e até mesmo em PHP5.6.
>
> Sugiro que se tiver interesse em ver alguns recursos específicos testados, você possa acessar o site https://www.phpbench.com/

Resumindo, em PHP *puro*, por segundo você conseguirá responder muito mais requisições HTTP por segundo, então se preocupar com string de aspas duplas, quando existem gargalos de problemas maiores que as pessoas se envolvem, não estou afirmando para não usarem frameworks, estou só mostrando que aspas duplas nunca foi de fato um problema, só será em um cenário quase irreal (que citei no começo da resposta, sobre escrever uma string gigante manualmente e ainda fazer uma série de operações em loop).

Comment: Só uma duvida: essa história de ser mais rápido vem de existir alguma diferença (mesmo que insignificante) de performace entres os tipos de aspas?

Comment: @raphael deve ser daquela mesma história, que na época do PHP4 e começo do 5, cercavam a comunidade PHP: "include é mais rápido que require". Sim, contavam muito essa história, é mito, mas na época todo mundo acreditava, também tinha o outros mitos e pérolas que lembro de ter ouvido, justamente de pessoas que nunca se deram ao trabalho de por em pratica algo para confirmar, mas adoravam propagar suas teorias, lembro de ouvir algumas vezes pessoas dizerem: "OOP é mais rápido que procedural".

Comment: @raphael na teoria deveria haver, pois nas aspas duplas existe uma carga maior de processamento, pois o php precisa ficar verificando a cada caracter da string se existe um `$`, caso exista tem que verificar se ele está escapado ou não, para substituir ou não pelo conteúdo de uma variável, talvez fizesse alguma diferença na época do computador 386 ou 486, mas com a evolução dos computadores, é insignificante, mesmo ocorrendo mais processamento. Pessoalmente prefiro usar aspas simples quando não existem variáveis embutidas na string e aspas duplas quando possuem, para padronizar.

Comment: @Benilson é exatamente o que respondi, se precisa talvez escrever algo que vá usar o cifrão, ou algo que por acaso "case" com uma das *sequências de escape para caracteres especiais expandidos*, mas não deseja tal resultado seja convertido, use as aspas simples, até evitará possiveis enganos. Eu mesmo intercalo entre aspas duplas e simples, se for echo eu vou direto para o uso da virgula `,`, ex: `echo 'foo: ', $foo, 'bar: ', $bar;` e em algumas situações especificais (geralmente relacionado a sequências de escape para caracteres especiais expandidos (como \t, \n, etc), eu uso aspas duplas.

Comment: E só pra constar @Benilson, PHP5 foi lançado próximo a descontinuação dos processadores i486 (uma média de 2 a 3 anos entre o processador e a versão 5) , duvido muito que era algo para se considerar em servidores na época, e mesmo provavelmente em um teste nesse processador você iria notar uma diferença mínima.

Comment: poderia incorporar tudo isso desses comentários na resposta? Ai fica mais completo e termina o assunto.

Comment: @raphael mas já não está, na resposta eu falei sobre as sequências de escape para caracteres especiais expandidos (exemplos: \t, \n, etc) e sobre versões não mudarem (logo no começo da resposta, aonde falo de php5.x), pois mesmo antes já não tinha quase diferença. Qual parte você está sentindo falta exatamente?

Comment: sobre ser algo vindo do PHP4 e virar uma boa prática difundida, mesmo não significando um ganho real de performance no código. Seria mais um contexto de onde vem.

Comment: @Benilson o problema é que no PHP infelizmente existe escape dentro de aspas simples. Acaba tendo um parser envolvido no treco, infelizmente matando um pouco a "pureza" dessas strings também (apesar disso poder ser resolvido teoricamente na "compilação" e não na execução de fato) - https://ideone.com/DYSHZO. Mesmo assim, por diversas razões, se não é pra ter interpolação, o adequado é sempre `'` simples mesmo - nem que seja só por uma "questão filosófica" :D - Num mundo "ideal" a simples seria totalmente sem escape, para fazer mais sentido.

Comment: @Bacco sim, mas esse caso também existe para aspas duplas, eu citei o que seria um processamento a mais, que não ocorre no caso das aspas simples, mas como foi citado na resposta e no meu comentário anterior, o processamento a mais é irrelevante.